# Qual a diferença entre o .on("click", function() {}) e o .click(function() {})?

Tags: jquery

Eu geralmente uso, porque aprendi que era o *mais correto*, a atribuição de eventos da seguinte forma:

```
$('seletor').on('click', function(){});
```

No entanto, vejo muitos desenvolvedores utilizando a seguinte sintaxe:

```
$('seletor').click(function (){});
```

Apesar de terem me falado que o `.on` é o mais recomendado, eu não entendi direito o porquê. Então, na prática, qual a diferença de usar um ou outro?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

É basicamente como é feita a associação para o elemento. `.click` se aplica ao DOM corrente, enquanto o `.on` (usando delegação) continuará valendo para novos elementos adicionados ao DOM depois da associação do evento.

Qual é melhor pra usar, eu diria que depende do caso.

Exemplo:

```html
<ul id="afazer">
  <li>Afazer 1</li>
  <li>Afazer 2</li>
  <li>Afazer 3</li>
  <li>Afazer 4</li>
</ul>
```

Evento `.click`:

```
$("#afazer li").click(function() {
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Evento `.on`:

```
$("#afazer").on("click", "li", function() {
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Note que eu separei o seletor no `.on`. Já vou explicar o porquê.

Suponhamos que depois dessa associação, façamos o seguinte:

```
$("#afazer").append("<li>Afazer 5</li>");
```

É aí que você vai notar a diferença.

Se o evento foi associado via `.click`, o afazer 5 não obedecerá ao evento de clique, e assim não será removido.

Se foi associado via `.on`, **com o seletor separado**, ele obedecerá.

[Créditos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8018832/1418103)

Answer (score 48):

A grande vantagem do método [**`.on()`**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) é permitir a delegação para casos em que o `'selector'` for adicionado dinamicamente (depois de o código ter sido corrido).

Com outras palavras: o `.on()` serve para elementos descendentes do primeiro selector mesmo que não estejam presentes na altura em que o código é lido pois o jQuery só vai verificar o segundo selector na altura do evento ser detectado. Já o `.click()` só se aplica a elementos já criados/existentes na altura em que o código é lido.

Neste caso, usando delegação, a sintaxe é:

```
$(document).on('click','seletor', function(){ /* ... */ });
```

Eu usei `document` mas pode ser outro elemento, pai do `'seletor'`, que esteja presente na altura em que o [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) é lido. Assim na altura do clique com o rato, o `.on()` vai procurar o(s) elemento(s) delegados, usando só um *event handler* na memória.

No caso de queremos agarrar um evento a elementos que são criados dinamicamente ou carregados por ajax, em vez de adicionarmos um `.click()` a cada vez que ele é carregado/criado, então podemos ter somente um `.on()` para todos.

Usando `.click()` vai ser carregado um event handler por elemento na memória. Usando `.on()` com delegação é criado só um para todos os elementos.

No caso de não se usar delegação, como no exemplo da pergunta, então são semelhantes.

---

Links úteis para aprender mais sobre delegação de eventos em jQuery:

- [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>
- [Events and Event Delegation](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/events) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>
- [jQuery `.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>

Comment: É importante escolher o seletor "pai" para o qual o evento será delegado sendo o "ancestral mais próximo" possível. Em outras palavras: é melhor evitar carregar tudo nas costas do `document`, que é o ancestral comum a todos os elementos.

Comment: Por exemplo: se você quer capturar o click em células de uma tabela, que podem aparecer/sumir dinamicamente, ao invés de `$(document).on('click', 'td')` é preferível usar `$('table').on('click', 'td')` - a ideia é usar no seletor do elemento que captura o evento, o que seja mais próximo possível daquele que vai delegar o evento.

Answer (score 18):

De acordo com a [documentação](http://api.jquery.com/click/) `$('selector').click();` é apenas um atalho para `$('seletor').on('click', function() { });`

### Mas existe uma opção interessante do método .on:

```
$('div#container').on('click', 'button.alert', function() {
    alert(1);
    $('div#container').append('<button class="alert">Clique-me</button>');
});
```

Isso fará que todos os `buttons` com a classe `alert` disparem o evento, *inclusive* buttons criados dinamicamente dentro da `<div id="container">` após a execução do script. Esse efeito é desejável em diversos cenários, por exemplo com conteúdo carregado via ajax.

Veja um exemplo no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c2zLY/)

Answer (score 14):

`$('seletor').click(function (){});` é um atalho para `$('seletor').on('click', function(){});`. Ambos são equivalentes. porém o primeiro caso tem um outro uso que é bem diferente (o clicar), enquanto o segundo tem outros usos que são parecidos (adicionar outros tipos de listeners).

### **Por que usar o $('').on('click' ... ?**

Bem, usar ele facilita para o desenvolvedor saber que é so trocar o click por outro evento que esse handler vai adicionar o listener para esse novo evento. É mais *intuitívo*.

Outro ponto, que é uma questão de gosto pessoal, é que `$().click()` também serve para ativar a ação como se a pessoa tivesse clicado e o `$('').on('click'...` sempre será para adicionar o listener, e isso evita certa confusão. Mas, como disse, é uma questão pessoal.

### **Existe algum real problema em usar `$('seletor').click(function (){});`** ?

Segundo a documentação oficial em
http://api.jquery.com/click/ não há nenhum alerta especial, como caso de avisar que esse código estaria deprecated (i.e. ser removido em alguma versão futura), logo não há um impedimento forte em não usar ele.

Eu pessoalmente prefiro usar o outro modo. Mas por questões históricas muitos tutoriais na internet vão usar este modo aqui.

Answer (score 14):

No geral `.click()` é realmente um atalho pro `.on()`, sendo que o `.on()` serve pra qualquer evento, tanto os nativos quanto os customizados e não apenas o 
**click**, dessa forma se por acaso vocês estiver utilizando um elemento dinâmico o `.click()` pode não funcionar e com certeza o `.on()` vai.

Answer (score 8):

Gostaria de acrescentar mais um detalhe, enquanto o ".click" é especifico pra um evento o ".on" pode delegar a mesma função pra varios eventos
Ex.:

```
$('selector').on('click mouseleave mouseenter ...', function(){...})
```

no caso ele vai executar a função pra todos os eventos descritos no primeiro parametro separado por espaço

[documentação do metodo on](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data)

Comment: `.click` é apenas um atalho para `bind("click"`, e este ultimo também pode "delegar" vários eventos.

Comment: @Ben-Hur Batista Bem lembrado isso, o .on da para delegar mais de um evento ao elemento.