# Evento click JQuery no seletor .class

Tags: jquery, css, dom

Criei várias `div` recorrendo a jQuery onde atribui às mesmas a classe de CSS `numero`:

```
for(...)
textoHTML += "<div class='numero par'>"+sorteado+"</div> <!-- numero par-->\n";
...
textoHTML += "<div class='numero impar'>"+sorteado+"</div> <!-- numero ímpar-->\n";
$( "#quadro" ).html(textoHTML);
```

Quero poder clicar nesta `div` e recuperar o número sorteado.
Mas ainda não sei como fazer, é com o `innerHtml`? `this`?

Porém, parece que o evento de clique do rato não está funcionando:

```
$( "numero" ).click(function() {
   console.log("Clicou no número");
});
```

Com o código acima nada acontece. Pode ter algo a ver com o facto de que a classe de CSS `numero` da `div` criada não está originalmente no DOM?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As sua intuição estava correcta, é usando o `this` e o `innerHTML`.

#### O que está a faltar:

1. Precisa de um ponto no selector do jQuery para classes

   ```
       '.numero'
        ↑
   (ponto aqui)
   ```
2. Elementos criados dinamicamente precisam de [**ser delegados**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5199/129) no caso de estar a amarrar o `.click()` antes do ciclo `for` ter corrido.

   Se não estiver a amarrar o `.click()` antes do ciclo `for` ter corrido, pode usar o `click` como tem na pergunta, juntando o ponto à classe de CSS.

   ```
   $('#quadro').on('click', '.numero', function () {
   ```
3. Pode usar o `this` dentro da função `click`
4. Pode usar `this.innerHTML` dentro da função.

   Aqui vai é ficar a faltar um `parseInt()` para converter a *string* num numero no caso de querer usar aquele valor como numero. Se for só para mostrar e não precisa de fazer cálculos com o numero então pode usar só `var numero = this.innerHTML;` ou até `innerText`, em vez de `innerHTML`.

#### Exemplo pode ser visto [**aqui**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ehf5p/):

```
var textoHTML = '';
for (var sorteado = 0; sorteado < 30; sorteado = sorteado + 2) {
  textoHTML += "<div class='numero par'>" + sorteado + "</div> <!-- numero par-->\n";
  textoHTML += "<div class='numero impar'>" + (sorteado + 1) + "</div> <!-- numero ímpar-->\n";
}
$("#quadro").html(textoHTML);

$('#quadro').on('click', '.numero', function () {
  var numero = parseInt(this.innerHTML);
  alert(numero);
});
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo refactor à la @Zuul (TM)

Comment: Sergio, em algumas vezes trabalhando com o ".on" dessa forma: " $("#div").on('click',function(){ " não funcionou pra mim e somente usando " $(document).on("click","#div",function(){ " funcionou. Você sabe o motivo disso? Acha que vale abrir uma questão sobre isso?

Comment: @JoaoPaulo, dê uma olhada nesta resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5199/129

Comment: Quando vc usa o ID ele pega somente o primeiro elemento "[Selects a single element with the given id attribute](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)". Quando vc adiciona o evento no document e usa o seletor interno ID ele consegue mapear todos os elementos, mas "pesa" ficar adicionando tantos eventos no document.

Answer (score 4):

Caso tenha problemas relacionados à elementos que não estavam originalmente no DOM, você pode utilizar o método [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) do jQuery. Exemplo:

```
$( ".numero" ).on( "click", function() {
    //codigo
});
```

Até um tempo atrás era utilizado o método .live() para isso, mas este já está obsoleto.