# Click do jQuery não funciona em resultados vindos do $.post

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou desenvolvendo um botão de deletar no formulário de produtos que tenho, ele funciona assim

- Categoria 1 (Radio Button)
- Categoria 2 (Radio Button)

Após seleciona uma categoria, ele envia um comando `jQuery` para a função **$.post** e cria elementos `html` em uma parte do site com vários `radio button` assim:

- Filtro 1 (DELETAR)
- Filtro 2 (DELETAR)
- Filtro 3 (DELETAR)

Ao clicar em **(DELETAR)** ele tem que executar uma função com o seguinte código

```
 $("a#filtro").click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('valor'));
 });
```

Ou seja, o cliente vai selecionar uma categoria e ao selecionar irá gerar um HTML com **Radio Button** para filtros e ao selecionar um filtro ele da um `alert()` exibindo o valor do filtro. O Problema é que o código do `alert` não está executando, pois acho que é por causa que ele é adicionado por `$("#meusfiltros").html('codigo-html-aqui');` . Agora se eu clico em um link com a mesmo `div` **#filtro** ele exibe sem problemas, pois já estava na página na hora que carregou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exatamente como você suspeita aqui precisa delegar o evento desse `$("a#filtro").click(` pois ele não existia ainda quando esse código foi lido.

Visto que `#meusfiltros` já existia na página quando o código foi lido, então pode fazer assim:

```
$("#meusfiltros").on('click', "#filtro", function(){
// ou mesmo (ainda mais seguro) 
$(document).on('click', "#filtro", function(){
```

O método `.on()` é permite delegar o evento para casos em que o elemento for adicionado dinamicamente (depois de o código ter sido corrido).

Sugiro dar uma olhada a esta resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5199/129 sobre a diferença de usar o `.on()` e delegação de eventos.