# sobre ajax vs eventos atribuidos

Tags: jquery, ajax

Quando o documento fica pronto, `$(document).ready`, eu envio uma solicitação AJAX para uma página PHP que gera uma tabela que eu coloco no meu body, mas,... abaixo dessa requisição ajax, tenho funções que mexem com eventos desta tabela, como `hover` na linha, clique no botão que tá na tabela gerada, e por ai vai..), mas as funções estas relacionadas a tabela não estão funcionando, o código está OK, sem erros de sintaxe.

Quero saber se, por a tabela gerar dinamicamente, quando eu associo eventos a ela, pode ser que os eventos não são atribuídos porquê ela ainda não foi gerada ou algo do gênero?

Código da requisição ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function attform() {
$(".table").find("tbody").empty();
$.ajax({
url:"action/action.php",
method:"POST",
data:{acao:"attform"},
success: function(data){
$("tbody").append(data);
}
}); // fim ajax
}); // fim attform()
});

        </script>
```

Logo após ele, tenho um documento js.js que basicamente tem funções como está:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".modificar").hover(

function () {
    these = $(this);
    $(these).parent().css("background-color", "blue");
},

function () {
    $(these).parent().css("background-color", "white");
});
});
```

Veja que, `$(".modificar")`, é uma classe de um botão que vai ser gerado dinamicamente pela requisição ajax que fiz ali em cima..

Comment: Parece um caso tipico onde precisas de delegar os eventos. Podes juntar o código a que te referes?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/36811/129

Comment: @Sergio, editei e coloquei os scripts, mas veja, se este for o problema, posso então substituir por `$(".modificar").on(hover,function(){},function{});`?

Comment: aplicação do método `on()` então é para colocar eventos em objetos que podem, **ou não**, terem sidos criado dinamicamente?

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus Não, [depende de como o `.on()` for usado](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5196/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-o-onclick-function-e-o-clickfunction)

Comment: Isso devia ser feito com CSS... não queres ir por essa via?

Comment: Devia mesmo, mas fiz desta forma para escapar do convencional! 
@bfavaretto, me corrija se estiver errado e precisar ir ler mais.. Mas, o seletor do on() deve existir, já o segundo parâmetro é aquele que foi gerado dinamicamente, não é?
Tipo: `$(deveexistir).on(evento,vaisergeradodinamicamente,function(){...});`

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus Exatamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso deve ser feito com CSS e não com JS...

Se quiseres fazer com JS/jQuery neste caso tens de usar delegacão e porque o `.hover()` não permite isso sugiro usares o `.on()` assim:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on('mouseenter', '.modificar', function(){
        $(this).parent().css("background-color", "blue");
    });

    $(document).on('mouseleave', '.modificar', function(){
        $(this).parent().css("background-color", "white");
    });

});
```

Mais leitura acerca de delegacão: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5199/129

Comment: Valeu pelo aval, era exatamente isso, como foi gerado dinamicamente, deleguei usando `on()` e ficou perfeito. Agradeço a ambos pelo compartilhamento do conhecimento! :)

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus bom que pude ajudar! Dá uma olhada à pergunta que linkei na resposta. Tem duas boas explicações sobre delegação.