# Setar click para elementos ainda não existentes

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(".item").on('click',function(){
  alert($(this).text());
});

count=0;

$("#new").on('click',function(){
  count++;
  $li = $("<li class='item'>LI "+count+"</li>");
  $("ul").find('.item').last().after($li);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class='item'>LI 0</li>
<li id='new'>+ Adicionar li</li>
</ul>
```

Fiz um código simples acima para demonstrar o problema em questão.

Como podem ver, após um novo elemento `<li>` ser adicionado ele não herda o evento de click que foi setado antes no código

Como poderia fazer com que ele herde esse evento sem precisar setar novamente toda vez que um `<li>` for adicionado?

Comment: você deve setar a `class="item"` no li que esta adicionando

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert você tinha razão, realmente esqueci de adicionar. mas como testado antes não teve efeito algum.
Alterei agora e continuou o mesmo problema

Comment: @Sergio, na verdade não sei se foi bem um duplicata...

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha essa pergunta tem respostas bem completas sobre o problema de delegação. Se não fôr essa pode ser [esta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/36812/129) ou [esta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/37733/129) ou outras mais com o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

neste caso você pode usar o evento `on` sobre a `ul` e passar as `li` como segundo parametro.

```
$("ul").on('click', '.item', function(){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

no exemplo acima, ele vai aplicar o evento `click` para todos os elementos com a classe `.item` pertecentes a `ul`, idenpedente do `.item` já existir ou não.

```js
$("ul").on('click', '.item', function(event){
  alert(this.textContent);
});

count=0;

$("#new").on('click',function(){
  count++;
  $li = $("<li class='item'>LI "+count+"</li>");
  $("ul").find('.item').last().after($li);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class='item'>LI 0</li>
<li id='new'>+ Adicionar li</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sim sim! isso mesmo, funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado!