# Como remover linha de tabela gerada dinamicamente com JQuery?

Tags: jquery

Eu gostaria que uma das colunas geradas automaticamente na tabela fosse tivesse uma função para excluir a linha, porém o on click não está funcionando. Como eu deveria fazer isto ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
            $("#associar1").on("click", function(e){        
     var coluna = "<tr>";
                             coluna += "<td width='40%'  align='center'><input type='text' disabled = 'disabled'   value= "+$("#canal").val()+" name='vigenciaCanalVendaVO.canalVendaVO.codigo'/></td>";
                             coluna +="<td width='40%'  align='center'><input type='text'  mask = '99/99/9999' disabled = 'disabled' data-mask='data' data-date-type='default' size='12' maxlength='10'  value="+$("#dataInicioVigencia").val()+" name='vigenciaCanalVendaVO.dataInicioVigenciaAssociacaoPlano'/>"
                             coluna +="At&eacute;<input type='text' mask='99/99/9999'  data-mask='data' disabled = 'disabled' data-date-type='default' size='12' maxlength='10'  value="+$("#dataFimVigencia").val()+" name='vigenciaCanalVendaVO.dataFimVigenciaAssociacaoPlano'/></td>";
                             coluna +="<td align='center'><img src='/includes/images/bt_remover.gif' id='remover' style='cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;'/></td>";
                             coluna += "</tr>";               
                             //alert(coluna);    
                        ($('#tabelaCanais')).append(coluna);
                    });
    });
    $("#remover").on("click",function(e){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tem de delegar esse evento pois esse elemento #remover é inserido depois do jQuery ter sido lido. Expliquei esta questão da delegação [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5199/129).

Pode fazer assim:

```
$("#tabelaCanais").on("click", "#remover", function(e){
```

Sugiro também mudar esse ID para classe, senão o jQuery só vai encontrar o primeiro #remover e não vai funcionar nos outros. Assim o código que sugiro é:

```
$("#tabelaCanais").on("click", ".remover", function(e){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 
});
```

e HTML:

```
<img src='/includes/images/bt_remover.gif' class='remover' style='cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;'/>
```

Nota: uso o [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) pois é mais fiável do que `.parent().parent()` caso tenha mais elementos no DOM entre a imagem e a linha.

Comment: Excelente sua resposta, eu preciso fazer a mesma coisa só que depois da execução de um Ajax, quando eu faço fora do Ajax funciona, mas quando coloco dentro do success do Ajax não funciona, tenho que modificar alguma coisa?

Comment: @AlanAlmeida funciona da mesma maneira. O que é importante é garantir que o `.on()` é aplicado sobre um elemento que já estava no DOM. Caso não saiba o mais seguro é usar `$(document).on(...etc`

Comment: @AlanAlmeida se não conseguir coloque uma pergunta que vai ter ajuda a resolver.

Comment: postei uma pergunta, nesse link http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37748/executar-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-jquery-em-tabela-gerada-dinamicamente-ap%C3%B3s-um-ajax se puder dar uma olhada.

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: @AlanAlmeida vi agora a pergunta. A resposta do brasofilo está certa. O `this` dentro do AJAX não é o mesmo que fora, tem de usar uma referência tipo `vat self = this;` ou como ele fez lá.