# Executar função jQuery em tabela gerada dinamicamente após um AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso executar a função abaixo, após a requisição do AJAX ele tem que remover a linha da tabela, se eu coloco o código que remove a linha direto na função ele remove a linha normalmente, mas se eu coloco dentro do success do AJAX ele não remove a linha e  executa o `alert` normalmente no final.

```
$('#tabelaMaterial').on('click', '.icon-remove', function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/RCM/RemoveItemCarrinho",
        type: "POST",
        success: function () {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            alert("Material removido!");
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É uma questão de escopo, o `this` lá no `success` é outra coisa:

```
$('#tabelaMaterial').on('click', '.icon-remove', function (event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/RCM/RemoveItemCarrinho",
        type: "POST",
        success: function () {
            $this.closest('tr').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

<sub>**Relacionado**: [Qual a diferença entre $(this) e $this e this?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/37770/201)</sub>

Comment: Funcionou certinho, muito obrigado.

Comment: @Alan, acrescentei um link importante na resposta.