# Como retornar respostas diferentes com valores diferentes em Classes iguais?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho dois valores diferentes que devem retornar respostas diferentes, porem as classes são iguais, como resolver ?

Veja que a respostas está errada.

```css
.Container-Produto{display:block;border:solic 1px #ccc;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Container-Produto">
                    <div class="Preco">99,00</div>
                    <a class="Frete-a"></a>
                    </div>  
                    
                    <div Class="Container-Produto">
                    <div class="Preco">98,00</div>
                    <a class="Frete-a"></a>
                    </div> 


<script>
         jQuery("document").ready(function($){
         $('.Preco').ready(function() {
         var preco = $('.Preco').text();
         preco = parseFloat( preco.replace( '.', '' ).replace( ',', '.'         ) );
         if( preco > 98.99 ) {
         $('.Frete-a').text( 'Frete Grátis' );
         } else {
         $('.Frete-a').text( 'Sem Frete Grátis' );
         }
         });
         });
</script>
```

Comment: @Bacco tem idéia que como resolver isso aqui ?

Comment: Só para informar, o Bacco não recebeu notificação do seu comentário acima, Gladson. Os usuários só são notificados com `@` se eles já tiverem comentado na pergunta ou resposta em questão.

Comment: De fato, eu só vi pq eu entrei aqui pra ler. Mas as 2 respostas contemplam o caminho correto pra solucionar, enão +1 em ambas ;)

Comment: Obrigado @bfavaretto, agora entendi como funciona

Comment: @Bacco, te perguntar uma coisa, no caso o .next() adiciona retorno no caso o $(this) na tag subsequente ao ".Preco", mas e se haver outra tags qualquer entre eles, como eu resolvo ?

Comment: Creio que é fundamental você entender os **seletores** do jQuery, pois são a base de qq coisa que você vá fazer. Em português, achei um video aqui numa pesquisa rápida, nao sei se presta pq assisti só o começo, mas tente ver se resolve: http://vimeo.com/15991889

Comment: E pra vc saber, o next da forma que foi posto na resposta aceita está retornando o "próximo .Frete-a" e nao a proxima tag qualquer.

Comment: Eu procurei ver todos os seletores hoje, testei vários, mais não achei um que selecionasse a tag que eu quero que aparece o texto "Frete Grátis", vou ver o vídeo, muito obrigado

Comment: @Bacco, por que .find() não funciona nesse caso, ela não deveria encontrar a TAG com a classe que eu quisesse ?

Comment: .find é pra achar uma tag dentro de outra. Se estiver fora, pode precisar de outros seletores. Melhor dar uma empenhada boa no estudo dos seletores e fazer mais testes (corte o código desejado e teste nele em separado num SQL Fiddle, por exemplo), pois você sempre vai estar esbarrando neste tipo de problema.

Comment: to no Dreamweaver aqui desde de cedo, não to conseguindo mesmo selecionar onde eu quero que executar a função,...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se tem vários elementos com essas classes, é preciso fazer um loop no conjunto e alterar um por um. Você pode fazer isso com jQuery usando o [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.Preco').each(function() {
         var preco = $(this).text();
         preco = parseFloat( preco.replace( '.', '' ).replace( ',', '.') );
         if( preco > 98.99 ) {
             $(this).next('.Frete-a').text( 'Frete Grátis' )
         } else {
             $(this).next('.Frete-a').text( 'Sem Frete Grátis' );
         }
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Container-Produto">
    <div class="Preco">99,00</div>
    <a class="Frete-a"></a>
</div>  
                    
<div Class="Container-Produto">
    <div class="Preco">98,00</div>
    <a class="Frete-a"></a>
</div>
```

Note os outros ajustes que fiz no seu código:

1. Não existe `$('.Preco').ready`, usei `.each` no lugar.
2. Dentro do loop, `this` é o `div` de preço sendo acessado no momento
3. Usei `.next` relativo ao div de preço para pegar a âncora de frete seguinte

Comment: Obrigado @bfavaretto♦ entendi agora

Answer (score 7):

O teu código em jQuery está quase lá, mas quando trabalhas com múltiplos elementos tens que te referir a cada elemento um a um, para que possas agir sobre cada um dos diversos elementos encontrados sem influenciar os restantes.

Para o efeito podes fazer uso do `this` em JavaScript ou `$(this)` em jQuery. 
[Ver esta pergunta para saber mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/37770/223).

Como te estás a referir a uma classe e não ao elemento X, a alteração ocorre em todos os que tenham a classe a que te referiste.

Para evitares isso, em jQuery tens a função [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) que te permite iterar por cada elemento:

```
jQuery("document").ready(function($){

    // Por cada elemento com classe `Preco`
    $('.Preco').each(function() {

        var $this = $(this),                                    // eu
            preco = parseFloat($this.text().replace(",", ".")); // o meu valor

        // Definir o texto a usar
        var frete = ((preco > 98.99) ? '' : 'Sem ') + 'Frete Grátis';

        // Atualizar elemento a seguir a "eu"
        $this.next('.Frete-a').text(frete);
    });
});
```

```js
    jQuery("document").ready(function($){

        // Por cada elemento com classe `Preco`
        $('.Preco').each(function() {

            var $this = $(this),                                    // eu
                preco = parseFloat($this.text().replace(",", ".")); // o meu valor
    
            // Atualizar elemento a seguir a "eu"
            var frete = ((preco > 98.99) ? '' : 'Sem ') + 'Frete Grátis';

            $this.next('.Frete-a').text(frete);
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Container-Produto">
    <div class="Preco">99,00</div>
    <a class="Frete-a"></a>
</div>  

<div Class="Container-Produto">
    <div class="Preco">98,00</div>
    <a class="Frete-a"></a>
</div>
```

---

Exemplo também disponível no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/99h3uhqL/).

Comment: Obrigado @Zuul...