# Como diferenciar inputs que possuem mesma class?

Tags: jquery

Eu gostaria de, ao clicar em um input, preencher uma variável com o valor informado, porém esses inputs são criados dinamicamente com um iterator e todos os inputs possuem a mesma class. Tem como identificar qual input foi clicado e pegar o valor somente dele?

O Iterator está assim:

```
    <s:iterator value="planoVO.listaDeVigenciasCanalVendaVO" var="vigenciasPlanoCanalVenda">
                <tr>
                    <td width='40%'  align='center'>
                    </td>
                    <td width='40%'  align='center' >
                       <s:if test="%{status == 'Vigente'}">
                                 <input type="hidden" name="canalVendaVO.codigo"  id="codigoCanalVenda" class="codigoCanalVenda" value='<s:property value="canalVendaVO.codigo" />' />
                                 <input type="hidden" name="canalVendaVO.nome"  id="nomeCanalVenda" class="nomeCanalVenda" value='<s:property value="canalVendaVO.nome" />' />
                                 <s:property value="dataInicioVigenciaAssociacaoPlano"/>
                                 <input type="hidden" name="dataInicioVigenciaAssociacaoPlano"  id="dataInicioVigenciaAssociacaoPlano" class="dataInicioVigenciaAssociacaoPlano" value='<s:property value="dataInicioVigenciaAssociacaoPlano" />'/>
                                 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;At&eacute;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                 <input type='text' data-mask="data" data-date-type="default"    size='10' maxlength='10' 
                                 value='<s:property value="dataFimVigenciaAssociacaoPlano"/>' id="dataFimVigenciaAssociacaoPlano" class="dataFimVigenciaPlanoVigente" />
                                 <input type="hidden" name="dataInicioAntesDeAlteracao" id="dataInicioAntesDeAlteracao" class="dataInicioAntesDeAlteracao" value='<s:property value="dataInicioVigenciaAssociacaoPlano" />'  />
                                 <input type="hidden" name="dataFimAntesDeAlteracao" id="dataFimAntesDeAlteracao" class= "dataFimAntesDeAlteracao" value='<s:property value="dataFimVigenciaAssociacaoPlano" />'  />
                      </s:if>
```

O JQuery está assim :

```
 $('.dataFimVigenciaPlanoVigente').on('change', function(e){
      var $this = $(this);

      var dataFimVigenciaPlanoVigente = $this.parent('td').find('.dataFimVigenciaPlanoVigente').val(); //( $('#dataFimVigenciaPlanoVigente').val();
      var nomeCanalVenda =  $this.parent('td').find('.nomeCanalVenda').val();
      var dataInicioVigenciaPlanoVigente =$this.parent('td').find('#dataInicioVigenciaAssociacaoPlano').val();
      var codigoCanalVenda = $this.parent('td').find('.codigoCanalVenda').val();
      var dataInicioAntesDeAlteracao = $this.parent('td').find('.dataInicioVigenciaAssociacaoPlano').val();
      var dataFimAntesDeAlteracao = $this.parent('td').find('.dataFimAntesDeAlteracao').val();
```

Comment: pelo ID? no iterator provavelmente existe a opção de voce nomear com um id diferente, não?

Comment: A questão parece ser muito simples conforme já demonstrou o @MarceloBonifazio. Se tem algo que não estamos conseguindo ver, poste mais detalhes na pergunta. Se possível poste o código que você está trabalhando para ajudar de forma mais específica.

Comment: Eu poderia por um contador para diferenciar cada input?

Comment: No código do teu iterador, onde está o `dataFimVigenciaPlanoVigente` ao qual estás a anexar um evento de `change` ?

Comment: Ah! Perdão, acabei não pegando a parte importante. Vou editar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Recolher valor do próprio

Tu estás a anexar o evento `change` ao campo que referes ser o que pretendes recolher o `value`, pelo que para recolheres o `value` dele mesmo, basta referires-te ao objeto `this` ou a sua representação em jQuery `$(this)`:

```
$('.dataFimVigenciaPlanoVigente').on('change', function(e){
  var $this    = $(this),
      meuValor = $this.val();
//...
```

<sup>Ver a [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/39893/223) do @Borachio nesta tua pergunta.</sup>

A tua linha:

```
var dataFimVigenciaPlanoVigente = $this.parent('td').find('.dataFimVigenciaPlanoVigente').val();
```

É desnecessária pois estás a arrancar do campo, subir ao elemento pai `td`, localizar o próprio campo e depois extrair o seu `value`. Podes reduzir a linha para:

```
var dataFimVigenciaPlanoVigente = $this.val();
```

<sup>Assunto relacionado: [Qual a diferença entre $(this) e $this e this?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/37770/223).</sup>

### Cache de elementos

Para o elemento com a classe `dataFimVigenciaPlanoVigente`, estás a colocar a sua referência no DOM em cache, contudo, para localizares o seu elemento pai estás constantemente a realizar uma pesquisa.

O teu código poderia passar para:

```
$('.dataFimVigenciaPlanoVigente').on('change', function(e){
  var $this = $(this),
      $wrap = $(this).parent('td');
// ...
```

E depois para usar:

```
var nomeCanalVenda =  $wrap.find('.nomeCanalVenda').val();
```

### Duas vezes o mesmo valor

Ao recolheres os valores dos vários `input`, existe um que estás a recolher duas vezes para duas variáveis distintas:

```
// Aqui por ID ao input dataInicioVigenciaAssociacaoPlano
var dataInicioVigenciaPlanoVigente = $this.parent('td').find('#dataInicioVigenciaAssociacaoPlano').val();

// ...

// Aqui por Class ao input dataInicioVigenciaAssociacaoPlano
var dataInicioAntesDeAlteracao = $this.parent('td').find('.dataInicioVigenciaAssociacaoPlano').val();
```

### Trabalhar com "irmãos"

Dado estares a trabalhar com elementos irmãos, não tens necessidade de localizar o `parent`, podes fazer uso do método [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) que te devolve os elementos "irmãos":

Onde tens:

```
var nomeCanalVenda =  $this.parent('td').find('.nomeCanalVenda').val();
```

Passarias a ter:

```
var nomeCanalVenda =  $this.siblings('.nomeCanalVenda').val();
```

Menos código, melhor entendimento.

```js
$('.dataFimVigenciaPlanoVigente').on('change', function(e){

    var $this = $(this);

    var dataFimVigenciaPlanoVigente    = $this.val(),
        nomeCanalVenda                 = $this.siblings('.nomeCanalVenda').val(),
        dataInicioVigenciaPlanoVigente = $this.siblings('.dataInicioVigenciaAssociacaoPlano').val(),
        codigoCanalVenda               = $this.siblings('.codigoCanalVenda').val(),
        dataInicioAntesDeAlteracao     = $this.siblings('.dataInicioAntesDeAlteracao').val(),
        dataFimAntesDeAlteracao        = $this.siblings('.dataFimAntesDeAlteracao').val();

    // Apenas para debug
    $("#valoresObtidos").html("Valores obtidos: " + dataFimVigenciaPlanoVigente +" "+ nomeCanalVenda +" "+ dataInicioVigenciaPlanoVigente +" "+ codigoCanalVenda +" "+ dataInicioAntesDeAlteracao +" "+ dataFimAntesDeAlteracao);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="canalVendaVO.codigo" id="codigoCanalVenda" class="codigoCanalVenda" value="1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="canalVendaVO.nome" id="nomeCanalVenda" class="nomeCanalVenda" value="2" />
                <input type="hidden" name="dataInicioVigenciaAssociacaoPlano" id="dataInicioVigenciaAssociacaoPlano" class="dataInicioVigenciaAssociacaoPlano" value="3" />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;At&eacute;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type='text' data-mask="data" data-date-type="default" size='10' maxlength='10' value="4" id="dataFimVigenciaAssociacaoPlano" class="dataFimVigenciaPlanoVigente" />
                <input type="hidden" name="dataInicioAntesDeAlteracao" id="dataInicioAntesDeAlteracao" class="dataInicioAntesDeAlteracao" value="5" />
                <input type="hidden" name="dataFimAntesDeAlteracao" id="dataFimAntesDeAlteracao" class="dataFimAntesDeAlteracao" value="6" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<!-- apenas para debug -->
<div id="valoresObtidos"></div>
```

### Multiplas variáveis

Quando pretendes declarar múltiplas variáveis em JavaScript, não tens necessidade de estar constantemente a escrever `var`, podes fazer uso do separador `,` da seguinte forma:

```
var dataFimVigenciaPlanoVigente    = $this.val(),
    nomeCanalVenda                 = $this.siblings('.nomeCanalVenda').val(),
    dataInicioVigenciaPlanoVigente = $this.siblings('.dataInicioVigenciaAssociacaoPlano').val(),
    codigoCanalVenda               = $this.siblings('.codigoCanalVenda').val(),
    dataInicioAntesDeAlteracao     = $this.siblings('.dataInicioAntesDeAlteracao').val(),
    dataFimAntesDeAlteracao        = $this.siblings('.dataFimAntesDeAlteracao').val();
```

### IDs repetidos

No teu código, o mesmo está a aplicar `id` aos `input`, mas como tens esses `input` dentro de um ciclo, o que vai acontecer é que vais acabar por ficar com os IDs repetidos na página.

De acordo com as normas, [um `id` é um seletor único](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors), sendo uma forma de referenciar um único objeto. Já as [classes são seletores comuns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) sendo as mesmas uma forma de referências múltiplos elementos de uma só vez.

Por exemplo, onde tens:

```
<input type="hidden" name="canalVendaVO.codigo"  id="codigoCanalVenda" class="codigoCanalVenda" value='<s:property value="canalVendaVO.codigo" />' />
```

Deverás alterar para:

```
<input type="hidden" name="canalVendaVO.codigo" class="codigoCanalVenda" value='<s:property value="canalVendaVO.codigo" />' />
```

A ideia é remover todos os `id` desses campos que vão ser repetidos pelo ciclo evitando assim resultados imprevisíveis por parte do JavaScript.

---

## Código otimizado

O teu código com as correções e sugestões em cima referidas fica conforme em baixo apresentado:

- Com uso do `parent`

  ```
  $('.dataFimVigenciaPlanoVigente').on('change', function(e){

      var $this = $(this),
          $wrap = $this.parent();

      var dataFimVigenciaPlanoVigente    = $this.val(),
          nomeCanalVenda                 = $wrap.find('.nomeCanalVenda').val(),
          dataInicioVigenciaPlanoVigente = $wrap.find('.dataInicioVigenciaAssociacaoPlano').val(),
          codigoCanalVenda               = $wrap.find('.codigoCanalVenda').val(),
          dataInicioAntesDeAlteracao     = $wrap.find('.dataInicioAntesDeAlteracao').val(),
          dataFimAntesDeAlteracao        = $wrap.find('.dataFimAntesDeAlteracao').val();
  });
  ```

  Exemplo no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/1tauxa2b/).
- Com uso do `siblings`

  ```
  $('.dataFimVigenciaPlanoVigente').on('change', function(e){

      var $this = $(this);

      var dataFimVigenciaPlanoVigente    = $this.val(),
          nomeCanalVenda                 = $this.siblings('.nomeCanalVenda').val(),
          dataInicioVigenciaPlanoVigente = $this.siblings('.dataInicioVigenciaAssociacaoPlano').val(),
          codigoCanalVenda               = $this.siblings('.codigoCanalVenda').val(),
          dataInicioAntesDeAlteracao     = $this.siblings('.dataInicioAntesDeAlteracao').val(),
          dataFimAntesDeAlteracao        = $this.siblings('.dataFimAntesDeAlteracao').val();
  });
  ```

  Exemplo no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/t2ww24z1/).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação. Mas acontece que ainda estou com esse problema de pegar sempre o valor do primeiro input. Logo após a atribuição de valores no Jquery eu coloquei um alert e o valor que aparece nele é do input de cima, não do que foi clicado.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação. Mas acontece que ainda estou com esse problema de pegar sempre o valor do primeiro input. Logo após a atribuição de valores no Jquery eu coloquei um alert e o valor que aparece nele é do input de cima, não do que foi clicado.

Comment: @user5515 Retificaste o teu código no sentido dos IDs serem únicos? É que se tens campos com IDs como está na tua pergunta e tens isso dentro de um ciclo, vais ficar com a página cheia de IDs repetidos e os resultados são imprevisíveis!

Comment: Era isso mesmo. Os IDs estavam repetidos. Apagando isso funcionou! Muito obrigado e desculpa qualquer coisa, sou iniciante.

Comment: @user5515 Sempre às ordens, estamos cá para ajudar :)

Answer (score 2):

use o objeto this. Por exemplo:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="button"/>
<input type="text" class="button"/>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $(".button").click(function(){
    this.value = "novo valor";
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ljb8bqr8/1/