# Preview campo input não funciona

Tags: javascript, html5, query

meu navegador não está exibindo a imagem. Tema algo errado com esse código?

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
     $("input[name='fun_imagem']").change(function ()
     {
         readImage($(this));
     });

});


function readImage(input) {

     var arquivo = new FileReader();
     arquivo.onload = function(e)
     {
          $("#imagem-figure-usuario").attr("src", e.target.result);
     };

     arquivo.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observei que você está passando uma lista de elementos do jQuery para a função `readImage`.

```
readImage($(this));
```

Você só precisa parar de cobrir `this` com o `$` jQuery. Se você não percebeu, `this` é um elemento HTML único, o elemento na lista `$("input[name='fun_imagem']")` que foi clicado. A prototype do jQuery não oferece uma propriedade `files`, nem função. Então:

```
readImage(this);
```

Se ele já estivesse em uma lista do jQuery (em outros casos) você só precisaria indexar com uma índice específica, por exemplo: `$ls[0]`, retornaria o primeiro elemento da lista.

Comment: Cara, relamente vc tem toda razão. Está funcionando perfeitamente agora. Vc tem algum link explicativo sobre essa diferença entre $(this) e this?

Comment: @PedroSoares Achei um para você no SOpt: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37770/qual-a-diferença-entre-this-e-this-e-this