# Sobre o each, this e o attr no jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Bom dia amigos, eu tenho uma grande dúvida em relação a esses atributos (se assim posso dizer), eu na verdade gostaria de entender de fato como funciona cada um deles, eu queria entender do por que usar cada um deles, desde já agradeço e me desculpem se a pergunta foi de alguma forma ruim.

Comment: Acho que isto http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ e isto http://api.jquery.com/attr/ são as melhores respostas.

Comment: Sobre `this` podes [ler nesta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/37771/129). E bem-vindo! Na próxima o ideal é colocar uma pergunta por tópico caso não exista ainda uma pergunta/resposta sobre o que procuras.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `each` é basicamente para fazer um `loop` atraves de um array ou objecto, por exemplo:

```
var meu_array = [1,2,3,4,5];
$.each(meu_array, function(index, value){
    console.log(index); // Exibira o numero do indice. 0, 1, 2...
    console.log(value); // Exibira o conteudo do elemento atual. 1,2,3...
});
```

O `attr` é responsavel por pegar os atributos de um elemento:

```
<div class="minha_classe" id="meu_id"></div>
$('.minha_classe').attr('id');
```

Você pode pegar qualquer atributo de um elemento usando apenas o `attr`

O `this` é um pouco mais complicado, mas suponho que a duvida seja referente a seleção de elementos com o `jquery`, o `this` referese ao proprio objeto que foi selecionado:

```
<div class="minha_classe" id="meu_id"></div>
$('.minha_classe').on('click', function() {
    console.log(this);
    // Exibira o elemento selecionado "<div class="minha_classe" id="meu_id"></div>"

    console.log($(this));
    // Exibira o elemento citado acima com funções "embutidas" do jquery como por exemplo o attr.
});
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado!!! literalmente era o que eu precisava assimilar aqui!