# JS: erro função not defined (ao chamar uma funcao dentro de outra)

Tags: javascript, funções

Estou tendo o seguinte erro: "minhafuncao is not defined"

Com a estrutura a baixo:

```
var myobject = object.extend({
   init: function () {
        minhafuncao();
   },

   minhafuncao: function() {
      console.log("oi");
   }
});
```

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37770/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-this-e-this-e-this/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o `this` para indicar o escopo da função:

```js
var obj  = {
  init: function() {
    this.minhafuncao();
  },

  minhafuncao: function() {
    console.log("oi");
  }
}
obj.init();
```

Comment: Olá, editei minha pergunta pois vi que estava faltando coisas. Tentei fazer como mencionou mas não funcionou, continua o erro. :(

Comment: O que é `object.extend` @sabrinabgbc? É de alguma outra biblioteca?

Comment: é so para estanciar o objeto

Comment: Deu certo, obrigada !