# Atribuir a uma variável o valor de um click em uma imagem, para fazer uma comparação

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Eu havia feito esse jogo usando textbox, e funcionou tudo ok, porém resolvi fazer uma modificação e ao invés de digitar coloquei imagens respectivas ao jokenpô e a imagem que o user clicar vai ser comparada e devolveria para o usuário quem ganhou, de inicio seria feito no alert mesmo. Meu problema está em pegar a opção do usuário e atribuir a uma variável e fazer essa comparação. Como posso fazer isso?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var choice = null;  
//Gera a opção do computador
var computerChoice = Math.random();

if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "Pedra";

} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "Papel";
} else {
    computerChoice = "Tesoura";
} 

//Pedra
$('#pedra, #papel, #tesoura').on('click',function(){

    if((computerChoice == choice) || (computerChoice == choice)||(computerChoice == choice))
            alert("Empate");
    else if (choice === "pedra") {
      if (computerChoice === "tesoura")
            alert("pedra vence");
        else {
            alert("papel vence");
        }
    }
    else if (choice === "papel") {
        if (computerChoice === "pedra")
            alert("papel vence");
        else {
            alert("tesoura vence");
        }
    }
    else if (choice === "tesoura") {
        if (computerChoice === "pedra")
            alert("pedra vence");
        else {
            alert("tesoura vence");
        }
    } 
   });

});
```

Comment: Você pode usar o atributo data e definir um valor para cada imagem. Ex: <img src="tesoura.jpg" data-valor="tesoura" />

Depois é só você recuperar o valor do atributo na hora do click. var choice = $(this).data("valor");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta utilizar o `$(this)` dentro da função do clique, no caso ele apontará para o botão que disparou o evento `click` e te permitirá identificar qual imagem foi escolhida.

No seu caso apenas adicinando isso na função do `click` já funcionará, pois pego o `ID` do elemento selecionado e comparo com a escolha do computador (*no caso coloquei `ID` em botões mas você pode fazer isso em imagens*)

```
 var choice = $(this).prop("id").toLowerCase(); 
 computerChoice = computerChoice.toLowerCase();
```

Entenda melhor como funciona o  [this/$(this)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37770/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-this-e-this-e-this/37771)

Fiz um *exemplo*, veja abaixo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var choice = null;  
//Gera a opção do computador
var computerChoice = Math.random();

if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "pedra";

} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "papel";
} else {
    computerChoice = "tesoura";
} 

//Pedra
$('#pedra, #papel, #tesoura').on('click',function(){

    //Obtenho a escolha do usuário
    var choice = $(this).prop("id").toLowerCase(); 
    computerChoice = computerChoice.toLowerCase();
    
    console.log('Escolha do pc: ' + computerChoice);
    console.log('Escolha da pessoa: ' + choice);

    if((computerChoice == choice) || (computerChoice == choice)||(computerChoice == choice))
            alert("Empate");
    else if (choice === "pedra") {
      if (computerChoice === "tesoura")
            alert("pedra vence");
        else {
            alert("papel vence");
        }
    }
    else if (choice === "papel") {
        if (computerChoice === "pedra")
            alert("papel vence");
        else {
            alert("tesoura vence");
        }
    }
    else if (choice === "tesoura") {
        if (computerChoice === "pedra")
            alert("pedra vence");
        else {
            alert("tesoura vence");
        }
    } 
   });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="pedra">Pedra</button>
<button id="papel">Papel</button>
<button id="tesoura">Tesoura</button>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, agora entendi, eu tinha usado o this. porém coloquei de uma outra forma, mais uma vez, obrigado pela excelente explicação e pelo exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode adicionar o atributo `name` com o determinado valor as suas imagens ou `div` que as pertencem

**Exemplo**

*Clique nas palavras para definir a variável.*

```js
$('div').on('click', function(){

  var escolha = $(this).attr('name');
  $('span').html('');
  $('span').html('O valor da variável é: '+escolha);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div name='pedra'>Pedra</div>
<div name='papel'>Papel</div>
<div name='tesoura'>Tesoura</div>

<span></span>
```

Comment: Obrigado mano, pela atenção e por me ajudar!

Comment: Por nada! Estamos ai.