# slideToggle(); abrir e fechar clicando no mesmo link, caso clicar em outro apenas alterar conteudo da div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso criar um efeito parecido com desse site [aqui](http://www.wickbold.com.br/linhas-produtos/grao-sabor/) quando clica no produto abre uma div com as infos dele ai se clico nele de novo essa div fecha, porem se eu clicar em outro produto e a div ja tiver aberta ele apenas altera o conteudo com as infos do produto que cliquei.

Eu estou tentando usar o slideToggle(); para fazer isso, mas quando eu clico em outro produto em vez de mudar so as infos ele fecha e abre a div de novo.

Segue meu código js:

```js
$('.menu li a').on('click', function() {
    var target = $(this).attr('rel');

    $("#" + target).slideToggle().siblings(".product-info").hide();

});
```

```html
/* Exemplo de como ta o codigo HTML */
<div>
    <div id="Valor Dinamico" class="product-info">
        <div class="container"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Consigo fazer esse efeito comm o slideToggle mesmo ou tenho que usar outro recurso?

**UPDATE:**

Add so um exemplo de como ta o codigo HTML não coloquei ele pq ta bem grande e tem trechos em PHP (tema wordpress).

**UPDATE 2**

o ID "valor dinâmico" é o mesmo valor do rel do elemento .

Comment: poder postar o html, para ficar mais functional

Comment: @MarceloBatista o html esta meio grande, eh um template de wordpress, mas vou editar e colocar um exemplo de como esta. Vlw

Comment: Sem mais html é difícil de ajudar. Mas só há um `product-info` para todos ? Ou cada produto tem o seu `product-info` ? O `rel` do `<a>` tem o que ?

Comment: @Isac mas o que falta é so conteudo, sim so tem um product-into o que muda é o container, cda produto tem seu container. O rel é o mesmo valor do id = "valor dinamico".

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( "ul > li" ).click(function() {
  $(".product-info").slideToggle('slow')
})
```

```css
div.product-info{
  background-color:red;
  padding:1rem;
  margin:1rem;
  color:#fff;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
  display:none;
}

div.product-info p{
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>slideToggle demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="menu">
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>
  </div>
    <div class="product-info">
        <p>Loren ipsum....m Loren ipsum....,Loren ipsum....</p>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Voce pode definir uma class para sua div e para seu link, e usa o closest 
e o next, tambem vale a pena ver o funcionamento do **this e do $(this)** do jquery, como ja me recomendaram. 
[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)
[$(this)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37770/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-this-e-this-e-this)

Comment: Não deu certo =/

Comment: basicamente o que voce quer fazer pode me explicar para ajuda-lo

Comment: Quero fazer o efeito que se encontra no link que postei la em cima, clicou no produto abre a div com infos, clicou em outro produto as infos mudam, se clicar no mesmo produto que ja tem as infos aberta a div com as infos fecha.

Porem aqui no meu projeto, quando eu clico em outro produto em vez de mudar so as infos ela fecha e abre novamente com as infos atualizadas, de resto ta ok.

Comment: Fiz um alteração no resposta.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode criar uma class css para definir uma posição inicial e adiciona essa classe e remover através do jquery exemplo:

```
$('div ou botão a ser clicado').click(function(){
       if(!$(this).hasClass('classe-criada-no-css')){
           $(this).addClass('classe-criada-no-css');
           $('div que recebera a ação').animate({'left': '0px'},300);
       }else{
          $(this).removeClass('classe-criada-no-css');
          $('div que recebera a ação').animate({'left': '-100%'}, 300);
       }
   });
```