# O que significa o símbolo "$" com parênteses para valores de uma variável

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber o que significa essa expressão que a variável recebe no JavaScript:

```
var wheight = $(window).height();
```

### Dúvidas

- O que seria o símbolo "$" com parênteses? E  o ponto?
- O que vem depois do ponto? O que vem dentro do parêntese?

Comment: [Se pesquisar direitinho vai ver que essa pergunta é duplicada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery?tab=Votes)

Comment: [Talvez essa responda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37770/qual-a-diferença-entre-this-e-this-e-this)

Comment: Ok, obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 4):

Em javascript você pode utilizar o simbolo do "$" como nome (identificador) de variável ou função.

por exemplo :

```
var $ = 0;
```

ou

```
function $(){}
```

No código postado, você provavelmente esta utilizando a biblioteca [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), que atribui o seu código em uma função, que recebe como parâmetro um Elemento html ou um seletor html.
Ao invocar o método ele retorna um objeto, que possui atributos ou funções podendo ser invocadas através do objeto retorna com o ponto.