# Porque os eventos jquery nao funcionam quando crio um objeto via innerHTML do Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou fazendo o seguinte código:

```
var botoesTela = "<button id='okcad' class='botao_padrao botao_ok' value='OK' onclick=''> <img src='/php/Images/OK.png' alt='OK' /> OK </button>";
divBotoes.innerHTML = divBotoes.innerHTML + botoesTela;
```

mas quando eu tento pegar o *click* no botão na pagina HTML

```
$("#okcad").click(function()
```

ele não faz nada...alguém sabe porquê?

Comment: Há algum erro no console? Quando o bind da função de click é realizado? Antes ou depois da inserção do botão no document?

Comment: Pode ser a ordem em que as coisas são feitas. Nesse caso você precisaria [delegar o evento](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5196/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-o-onclick-function-e-o-clickfunction/5199#5199).

Answer (score 3):

Duas razões (erros no código) que podem levar a esse problema:

### #1

**Problema:** O elemento é criado **depois** de esse jQuery ser lido.
**Solução:** Precisa delegar o evento.
**Novo código:** `$(document).on('click', "#okcad", function(){`

### #2

**Problema:** IDs duplicadas se eventualmente estiver a adicionar botões como esse várias vezes.
**Solução:** Use *classes* em vez de IDs ou gere IDs dinamicamente para serem unicas.
**Novo código:** `$(".botao_padrao.botao_ok").click(function(){`

---

Pode combinar as duas ideias e usar:  `$(document).on('click', '.botao_ok', function(){`