# Após filtrar conteúdo, jQuery não funciona

Tags: jquery, ajax, click

Fiz um código listando itens do banco de dados com PHP (usando data-id pra o jQuery "ler" o clique), porem quando filtra os itens usando Ajax, o clique para de funcionar.

PHP

```
while ($furni = $furnis->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo '<img src="./web-gallery/images/furnis/small_' . $furni['image'] . '" data-id="'.$furni['id'].'" />';
}
```

jQuery (completo: http://pastebin.com/BvAz0CRr)

```
success: function (e) {
     $(".small_items").html('');
     for (var i = 0; i < e.array.length; i++) {
          $(".small_items").append('<img src="./web-gallery/images/furnis/small_' + e.array[i].image + '" data-id="' + e.array[i].id + '" />');
     }
}
```

Explicando melhor, tenho uma outra função usando .click para pegar os dados do item e como falei, listados pelo PHP o .click funciona normalmente, mas quando filtra e lista pelo jQuery, o .click para de funcionar

Comment: Já tentou usar o `.on` ao invés do `.click`? Dê uma olhada [nessa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5196/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-o-onclick-function-e-o-clickfunction), talvez lhe ajude.

Comment: Eu estava usando o .on, mas sem separar o seletor, valeu pelo link! funcionou :D

Answer (score 1):

Substitui esta linha:

```
$('.small_items img').on('click', function () {
```

por esta:

```
$('.small_items').on('click', 'img', function () {
```

O que está a acontecer é que as imagens recebem um *oscultador de evento* quando corres essa linha que referi em cima. Mas depois tu removes o conteudo de `.small_items` com `$(".small_items").html('');` e isso remove os event handlers (*oscultadores de evento*).

Então tens de usar delegação para o oscultador de eventos ser amarrado a `.small_items` que está sempre presente na página, e só no momento do *click* ele vai verificar se é um elemento `img` para disparar o evento ou não.