# Excluir tr tabela html jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Caros, criei uma rotina que adiciona uma tr a uma tabela existente, e estou tentando criar um botao para remover esta tr, mas ainda não consegui.

Usei o seguinte codigo para adicionar a tr, este funciona normalmente:

HTML

```
<table id="Table">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>D</th>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background:white">
    <td>Item1</td>
    <td>Item2</td>
    <td>Item3</td>
    <td><input type="button" class="Remover" value="x" style="background:red;"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#Table').click(function(){
    var conta = 0;
    var dados = [$('#Item1').val(),$('#Item2').val(),$('#Item3').val(),$('#Item4').val()];
    var cols = '<tr style="background:white">';
    for(var i=0; i < 8; ++i){           
        if(dados[i] == ""){
            conta=1;
            } else{
            cols += '<td>'+dados[i]+'</td>';    
            }
    };
    if(conta==0){
    cols += '<td><input type=\"button\" id=\"Remover\" value="x" style=\"background:red;\" /></td>';
    cols += '</tr>';
    $("#InserirPedido tbody").append(cols);
    return false;
    }else{
        alert('Preencha todos os campos');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Tentei usar o seguinte codigo pra remover, porém sem sucesso:

```
$('#Remover').click(function () {
     $(this).closest('tr');
});
```

Comment: Não mudes a pergunta. Deixa como estava senão as respostas vão ficando erradas. Repara que eu usei uma classe com __R__ pequeno. Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/0686n0qy/

Comment: ops...desculpe Sergio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens dois problemas. Um é que não podes ter IDs duplicados, o outro é que o oscultador de eventos não é adicionado a HTML que ainda não existe, tens de usar delegação.

Usa classes nesse HTML que acrescentas:

```
cols += '<td><input type=\"button\" class=\"remover\" value="x" style=\"background:red;\" /></td>';
```

e depois usa delegação assim:

```
$('#Table').on('click', '.remover', function () {
     $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Podes [ler mais aqui sobre delegação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5199/129).

Answer (score 3):

Algo que você pode fazer é colocar *class* no lugar do *ID* 'remover'.

```
cols += '<td><input type=\"button\" class=\"remover-linha\" value="x" style=\"background:red;\" /></td>';
```

Daí você pode criar uma função jQuery.

```
$('#Table').on('click', '.remover-linha', function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut(300);
});
```

---

Como os objetos são criados dinâmicamente, o On deve ser utilizado.