# Evento click se perde na página seguinte na paginação

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, paginação, click

Desenvolvi uma página simples de paginação para meus estudos e estou tendo um problema no evento click quando vou para a página seguinte. Na primeira página o evento funciona mas qdo vou para a seguinte o evento parece se perder.  O que pode ser?

Segue abaixo o meu código.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
table { 
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
    text-align: center;
}

thead td {    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding: 2px;
}

thead th {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
}

#myTable td {
        cursor:pointer;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #D1E3E9);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#ffffff), to(#D1E3E9));
        text-align:center;
    }

#myTable  td:hover{
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #249ee4, #057cc0);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#249ee4), to(#057cc0));
    }

#myTable td:active
    {
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #057cc0, #249ee4);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#057cc0), to(#249ee4));
    }

div {
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
<script>
var dados = [
        ['Banana', '10,00'],
        ['Maça', '2,00'],
        ['Pera', '6,00'],
        ['Goiaba', '3,25'],
        ['Tamarindo', '1,50'],
        ['Cenoura', '0,75'],
        ['Alface', '0,99'],
        ['Tomate', '3,21'],
        ['Abacaxi', 'N/D'],
        ['Kiwi', '99,50'],
        ['Cebola', '1,15'],
        ['Alho', '1,02'],
        ['Abóbora', '4,75'],
        ['Pêssego', '2,33'],
        ['laranja', '2,99']
    ];

var tamanhoPagina = 3;
var pagina = 0;

function paginar() {
    $('table > tbody > tr').remove();
    var tbody = $('table > tbody');
    for (var i = pagina * tamanhoPagina; i < dados.length && i < (pagina + 1) *  tamanhoPagina; i++) {
        tbody.append(
            $('<tr>')
                .append($('<td>').append(dados[i][0]))
                .append($('<td>').append(dados[i][1]))
        )
    }
    $('#numeracao').text('Página ' + (pagina + 1) + ' de ' + Math.ceil(dados.length / tamanhoPagina));
}

function ajustarBotoes() {
    $('#proximo').prop('disabled', dados.length <= tamanhoPagina || pagina >= Math.ceil(dados.length / tamanhoPagina) - 1);
    $('#anterior').prop('disabled', dados.length <= tamanhoPagina || pagina == 0);
}

function obtemPosicaoCelula() 
{
        $("#myTable tbody td").click(function() {     

            var column_num = parseInt( $(this).index() ) + 1;
            var row_num = parseInt( $(this).parent().index() )+1;    

            $("#result").html( "Row_num =" + row_num + "  ,  Rolumn_num ="+ column_num );   
        });
}

$(function(){
    $('#proximo').click(function() {
        if (pagina < dados.length / tamanhoPagina - 1) {
            pagina++;
            paginar();
            ajustarBotoes();
        }
    });
    $('#anterior').click(function() {
        if (pagina > 0) {
            pagina--;
            paginar();
            ajustarBotoes();
        }
    });
    paginar();
    ajustarBotoes();
    obtemPosicaoCelula();

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Descrição</th>
            <th>Valor</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">Nenhum dado ainda...</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div>
<button id="anterior" disabled>&lsaquo; Anterior</button>
    <span id="numeracao"></span>
<button id="proximo" disabled>Próximo &rsaquo;</button>
</div>
<div id="result"> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Testa mudar `$("#myTable tbody td").click(function() { ` para `$("#myTable tbody").on('click', 'td', function() { ` - assim, usando delegacão o click não se perde.

Comment: Obrigado. Funcionou.

Answer (score 5):

O problema aqui parece-me de delegação de eventos.

Quando adicionas novo HTML com

```
tbody.append(
    $('<tr>')
        .append($('<td>').append(dados[i][0]))
        .append($('<td>').append(dados[i][1]))
```

estes novos `td` não existiam quando registaste este auscultador de eventos:

```
$("#myTable tbody td").click(function() {
```

Assim deves mudar

```
$("#myTable tbody td").click(function() {
```

para

```
$("#myTable tbody").on('click', 'td', function() {
```

e assim, [usando delegação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5196/129) o click não se perde pois só no momento em que o evento click chega ao `tbody` é que o jQuery vai ver se o `td` lá está, e não registar um auscultador de evento a cada `td` que existia no inicio da página correr.

Comment: Funcionou, mas só não entendi muito bem esse lance de delegação. Por que deve se colocar o TD? Se o evento é gerado é partir de button, por exemplo, deve se colocar o button em vez de TD? Se for a partir de uma imagem(figura)?

Comment: @Leandro tinha um erro no link na resposta, lamento. Corrigi agora. Dá uma olhada [no link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5196/129), no fundo o `.on(` fica á espera que o evento suba no DOM e quando ele ocorrer vai verificar se ele passou por um elemento `td`. Mesmo que o botão que na verdade iniciou o evento (ou seja o `event.target`)  seja outro que não o `td`.

Answer (score 0):

Peguei seu código e coloquei no jsfiddle (somente a parte pertinente a paginação) e aparentemente esta funcionando: https://jsfiddle.net/kgacc46u/

Comment: Fiz o mesmo teste aqui e tmb está ok! rs http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/poL41cvz/

Comment: Então problema resolvido certo?

Comment: Não está resolvido. Se você for na página 2, por exemplo, o click para de funcionar.

Comment: Se no seu link no jsfiddle fosse possível reproduzir o problema ficaria mais fácil de te ajudar.