# Jquery pegar a primeira e segunda tag dentro de uma div

Tags: jquery, html

Estou tentando pegar o primeiro e o segundo elemento dentro de uma div. Mas não estou conseguindo.

Estou querendo pegar os dois inputs dentro do **shipping_table**. E ao clicar nos inputs eles irão fazer uma função.

O HTML é:

```
<table class="table" id="shipping_table">   <tr style="cursor:pointer">
    <td style="width:16px;">
        <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" id="s2ba82f8be158554d1aefa1fd27ea9001" data-deliverytime="13" value="PAC|27.8|13" name="shipping_method" checked="checked">         </label>
    </td>
    <td onclick="toggle_shipping('s2ba82f8be158554d1aefa1fd27ea9001');" style="width:120px;">
        PAC     </td>
    <td onclick="toggle_shipping('s2ba82f8be158554d1aefa1fd27ea9001');">

        <strong>R$ 27,80</strong><br><span class="label label-info">Entrega em torno de 13 dias úteis</span>        </td>
</tr>

<tr style="cursor:pointer">
    <td style="width:16px;">
        <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" checked="checked" id="s527db0b075ea188067f95de4b5ab90e2" data-deliverytime="5" value="SEDEX|72.9|5" name="shipping_method">         </label>
    </td>
    <td onclick="toggle_shipping('s527db0b075ea188067f95de4b5ab90e2');" style="width:120px;">
        SEDEX       </td>
    <td onclick="toggle_shipping('s527db0b075ea188067f95de4b5ab90e2');">

        <strong>R$ 72,90</strong><br><span class="label label-info">Entrega em torno de 5 dias úteis</span>     </td>
</tr>
```

E O Javascript é:

```
$("#shipping_table input:eq(1)").click(function() {
  alert( "função aqui" );
});

$("#shipping_table input:eq(2)").click(function() {
  alert( "função aqui" );
});
```

Não tenho muita experiência com Jquery. Então se puderem ajudar eu agradeço.

Comment: Felipe, esses inputs são carregados com a página ou inseridos depois?

Comment: Acredito que são inseridos depois.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O código que tens é jQuery e parece-me certo, tendo em conta que o `:eq()` começa em `0`. Ou seja o primeiro input dentro desse `#shipping_table` será `:eq(0)`.

Porem se esse conteúdo é dinamico, então precisas de delegar esse evento. Nesse caso podes usar o `.on()` assim:

```
$("#shipping_table").on('click', 'input:eq(0)', function() {
  alert( "função 1 aqui" );
});

$("#shipping_table").on('click', 'input:eq(1)', function() {
  alert( "função 2 aqui" );
});
```

A diferênça em [delegar o evento usando `.on()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5199/129) é que o elemento pretendido não precisa estar na página na altura em que o auscultador de evento é registado. Somente na altura do evento ser acionado é que o jQuery vai fazer a verificação.

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hfaz4hvd/

Comment: Funcionou, consegue me explicar por que não funciona o outro código?

Comment: Juntei mais info na resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Isso resolve

```js
$(function (){
    $("#shipping_table input:eq(0)").click(function() {
      alert($(this).val());
    });

    $("#shipping_table input:eq(1)").click(function() {
      alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="shipping_table">   <tr style="cursor:pointer">
    <td style="width:16px;">
        <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" id="s2ba82f8be158554d1aefa1fd27ea9001" data-deliverytime="13" value="PAC|27.8|13" name="shipping_method" checked="checked">         </label>
    </td>
    <td onclick="toggle_shipping('s2ba82f8be158554d1aefa1fd27ea9001');" style="width:120px;">
        PAC     </td>
    <td onclick="toggle_shipping('s2ba82f8be158554d1aefa1fd27ea9001');">

        <strong>R$ 27,80</strong><br><span class="label label-info">Entrega em torno de 13 dias úteis</span>        </td>
</tr>

<tr style="cursor:pointer">
    <td style="width:16px;">
        <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" checked="checked" id="s527db0b075ea188067f95de4b5ab90e2" data-deliverytime="5" value="SEDEX|72.9|5" name="shipping_method">         </label>
    </td>
    <td onclick="toggle_shipping('s527db0b075ea188067f95de4b5ab90e2');" style="width:120px;">
        SEDEX       </td>
    <td onclick="toggle_shipping('s527db0b075ea188067f95de4b5ab90e2');">

        <strong>R$ 72,90</strong><br><span class="label label-info">Entrega em torno de 5 dias úteis</span>     </td>
</tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Qual é a diferença do código do Felipe para o código que propões? podes explicar porque o teu código resolve e como?

Comment: Bom, não funciona. Acho que é por que o input é inserido depois. Como resolver?

Comment: Felipe, o meu código é executado logo que a página é carregada. Se você carrega os inputs em outro momento seria melhor você mostrar em que momento isso é feito pra que eu consiga indicar como você pode vincular os eventos. A princípio é simples, é só atribuir os eventos ao inputs após a criação do elemento na tela.

Answer (score 1):

```
var element = $('#shipping_table').find('input');
element[0].click(function() {
  alert( "função aqui" );
});
element[1].click(function() {
  alert( "função aqui" );
});
```

Comment: É eles são gerados automaticamente. E se fosse pegar direto pelo ID seria melhor colocar o ID sem a div, já que o ID é único.

Comment: alterei o código para suprir sua necessidade

Comment: bom eu tentei, mas não funcionou. Não sei por que. =/