# Como encontrar um componente HTML no DOM após usar a função .append()?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Estou fazendo uma requisição para meu servidor com `$.get` do Jquery, e populando a minha tabela com o método abaixo :

```
$.get(/*[[@{/empregados/salariosMinimos.json}]]*/ 'consultaEstadoSalario',         {uf : uf,data : data})
        .done(function(salarioestado){
                $("#tabela-salario-estado tbody tr").remove();
                for(var i in salarioestado){
                    if(salarioestado[i].dataFim == null){
                        salarioestado[i].dataFim = "";
                    }
                    var linhaTabela = $("<tr><td> " + formateDateJson(salarioestado[i].dataInicio) + "  </td> <td> " + formateDateJson(salarioestado[i].dataFim) +" </td><td class='text-right'> " + currencyFormat(salarioestado[i].valor)+" </td> " + "<td ><button id='btnSelecionar' class='btnSelecionar pull-right btn btn-xs btn-primary' type='submit' title='selecionar'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span></button></td>" + "</tr>");
                    $("#tabela-salario-estado").append(linhaTabela);

                }
        });
```

O problema é que quando eu executo a função `.append()` ele criar lá minha visão certinha mas o *button* que coloco no `append` com o id='btnSelecionar' não é reconhecido no meu DOM, ou seja, eu não encontro esse id na página e não consigo fazer nenhum evento js com esse botão. Então qual seria a solução para ele reconhecer meu botão ?

Comment: Você está usando a função `on` do JQuery? Aqui pode te ajudar http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5196/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-o-onclick-function-e-o-clickfunction

Comment: coloquei agora $("#btnSelecionar").on("click",function(){
    alert("teste");
    $("#modal-consulta-salario").modal('hide');
   }); e não funcionou :| @Marconi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você não colocou onde você está criando o evento de click do botão vou supor o que eu acho que seja o problema.

O problema é o seguinte.

Você provavelmente está criando o evento de click do botão usando ou seu ID ou sua CLASS. Porém se você fizer isso ele apenas vai criar esse evento de click para elementos que já estejam presentes na sua página quando o .click() foi chamado.

Como você está criando elementos dinamicamente isso não funciona. Para funcionar você deve criar um **listener** (ou **delegated event handler**) para seus botões.

Aqui vai um exemplo:

```
$('#pagina_onde_esta_meu_botao').on('click', '.btnSelecionar ', function(){
    console.log(this.value);
});
```

Com isso você fez criou um evento na sua **página** onde vai ser criado seu botão. esse evento fica escutando (listener) a todo click de qualquer elemento que tenha a classe **btnSelecionar** mesmo que ele seja criado depois que todo DOM já foi carregado.

**OBS Importante**

ID's são identificadores dentro de um conjunto (grupo) de elementos. Não é uma boa prática criar N botões com o mesmo ID. Te aconselho a colocar ou um identificador que faça sentido para sua aplicação ou concatenar com o index do for.

```
... id='btnSelecionar'" + i + " ...
```

Por exemplo.

Comment: Muito Obrigado pelo retorno realmente funcionou só tive que colocar o $(document) em vez do nome da minha página .