# Como utilizar minha extensão do jQuery na função on?

Tags: jquery

No jQuery, sei que é possível estender e criar funções para certo tipo de operações através do `$.fn`.

Assim:

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.clickOut = function (callback) {

        var that = this;

        $(document).click(function (e) {

            if ( $(e.target).closest(that).size() > 0) {

                return;
            }

            $.isFunction(callback) && $.proxy(callback, that)(e);
        });
    }

})( jQuery )
```

A função funciona corretamente. Mas como posso fazê-la funcionar com a utilização de `on`, pois preciso atribuir a mesma para elementos criadas dinamicamente.

Existe alguma maneira de "criar uma função"(não sei outra maneira de dizer isso) para o `on` do `jQuery`?

Grosseiramente falando, queria que funcionasse como se fosse assim:

```
$('div').clickOut(); // Forma normal

// Forma que tentei, e não deu certo.
$('#my-uls').on('clickOut', 'li', function (...){});
```

Comment: A respeito do `on` temos essa referência: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5196/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-o-onclick-function-e-o-clickfunction

Comment: Assim você tentou? `$('#my-uls').on('clickOut', 'li', function (){ $(this).clickOut(); }); `

Comment: Vou tentar de novo. Não tinha dado certo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade a resposta do Emir Marques bateu na trave. O caminho é sim o `trigger`, que é necessário para disparar o evento. Todo evento disparado com `trigger` pode ser capturado com `on`. Assim:

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $(document).click(function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).closest(that).size() > 0) {
            $(e.target).trigger('clickOut');
            return;
        }
    });

    // Feito isso, você pode usar:
    $('#my-uls').on('clickOut', 'li', function (){
        // faz algo
    }); 

})( jQuery )
```

Comment: Olha, esse trecho `function ( $ ) {` é para definir o plugin. Não seria `$(function(){` ?

Comment: Com o `$`  vira um `document.ready`. Sem ele, é apenas uma closure para isolar escopo e garantir que `$ == jQuery`. Depende da sua necessidade

Comment: Pelo o que entendi a necessidade era implementar um método no jquery (no caso clickOut) que pudesse ser usado em qualquer elemento. Por isso no exemplo que citei, ele implemente esse método e em seguida faz o uso da trigger para simular o "on". Nesse teu exemplo seria necessário mais um passo que ser chamar o trigger e então implementar o on. Seria isso mesmo?

Comment: Eu entendi que ele queria usar o `on`, @EmirMarques. Talvez a pergunta não esteja clara mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Para isso você pode usar o método trigger.

**Nesse caso ao invés de usar:**

```
 $(<seletor>).on("clickOut", function(){
     /* Faz algo */
 });
```

**Você usa:**

```
 $(<seletor>).trigger("clickOut", function(){
    /* Faz algo */
 });
```

**Exemplo completo:**

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.clickOut = function (callback) {

        var that = this;

        $(document).click(function (e) {

            if ( $(e.target).closest(that).size() > 0) {

                return;
            }

            $.isFunction(callback) && $.proxy(callback, that)(e);
        });
    }

    $(<seletor>).trigger("clickOut", function(){
        /* Faz algo */
    });

})( jQuery )
```

Comment: Colocar o seletor junto com a declaração do código da biblioteca? Não acho uma boa ideia. Vou testar para ver se trigger funciona

Comment: Você não coloca junto a declaração. Coloquei dentro do onload da página. Você usa da mesma forma que o "on", porém troca esse pelo "trigger". Veja o exemplo de novo, editei o mesmo para ficar mais claro

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que compreendi da questão, você quer criar um `callback` para que apos executar o evento do `.on` ele executa sua função `clickOut`.

Para isso você deve chama-la dentro da função.

```
(function($){
    $.fn.alertX = function(x){
        alert(x)
    }
})(jQuery);

jQuery('body').on('click', 'input', function(){
    var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    jQuery(this).alertX(id);
});
```

[Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/n3wzaurh/1/)

OBS: ainda estou vendo se tem como fazer isso sempre dentro no método, tipo prototype.

Comment: O único problema das respostas todas é o seguinte: Eu criei o clickout para definir que, quando será clicado fora, vai ocorrer um evento (que é o callback da função). Se eu usar o click, vou estar atribuíndo um evento para o click no elemento. Aí acho que o clickout ficaria prejudicado.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Você quer criar um clickOut que não dependa do click? Aí acho que não dá, porque o clique fora é antes de tudo um clique. Na minha resposta, tentei mostrar como fazer com que o `on` capture um evento não-padrão (custom).

Comment: Entendi. Percebi isso também! Acha que deixo a pergunta ou deleto?