# construir uma condicional usando objeto

Tags: javascript, html

Há a possibilidade de criar uma condicional atribuindo a condicional dentro de um valor?
Fiz da maneira abaixo, mas não deu certo:

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="pg1" value="SIM"> TESTE <BR/>
<input type="radio" name="pg1" value="NÃO"> TESTE 2

<div id="esconde">
    <p>NADA</p>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[name='pg1']").click(function(){
        var valor = $(this).val();

        divShowOrHide({
            //valorEscolhido: valor,
            condicional: valor+" === SIM",
            hideDiv: "#esconde"
        });
    });

});
function divShowOrHide(obj){
    //alert(obj.condicional);
    if(obj.condicional){
        $(obj.hideDiv).show();
    } else {

        $(obj.hideDiv).hide();
    }
}
```

o Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vgh42jqb/

Comment: Recomendo a leitura de [Qual a diferença entre o .on(“click”, function() {}) e o .click(function() {})?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5196/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-o-onclick-function-e-o-clickfunction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No caso de um verdadeiro/falso, você pode fazer algo como:

```
divShowOrHide({
    //valorEscolhido: valor,
    condicional: valor === "SIM",
    hideDiv: "#esconde"
});
```

Ele vai atribuir à `condicional` o valor da avaliação `valor === "SIM"`

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vgh42jqb/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Essa seria uma alternativa

```
divShowOrHide({
    //valorEscolhido: valor,
    condicional: "'"+valor+"'"+" === 'SIM'",
    hideDiv: "#esconde"
});

function divShowOrHide(obj){
    //alert(obj.condicional);
    if(eval(obj.condicional)){
        $(obj.hideDiv).show();
    } else {

        $(obj.hideDiv).hide();
    }
}
```