# jQuery, botão fechar funciona apenas uma vez

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho uma caixa de texto que é gerada por um botão, e ela possui um botão com a função de fecha-la, porém ele só funciona uma vez, para a primeira caixa gerada, gostaria que ele funcionasse em todas que forem geradas posteriormente.

E nisso tenho um outro pequeno bug, ao retirar completamente o texto e manter pressionado o backspace a caixa encolhe e sobe pro menu.

[https://jsfiddle.net/h6orx7x0/10/](https://jsfiddle.net/wesleyfc000/h6orx7x0/10/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens de usar delegação de eventos:

```
$('#editavel').on('click', "#close-link", function() {
    $('#close').fadeOut();
});
```

O problema é que quando corres `$("#close-link").click(function(){` esse código não vai apanhar elementos que não existem aindem. Mas se delegares ao elemento que sempre existe, o `$('#editavel')` já vai funcionar.

Podes ler mais sobre isto aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5199/129

Nota: Os IDs têm de ser únicos, isso quer dizer que só deves ter 1 `#close-link` na página. Senão deves usar classes: `.close-link`

Comment: Excelente explicação, em parte resolveu meu problema, mas eu acabei me expressando errado.
Quando eu disse **"gostaria que ele funcionasse em todas que forem geradas posteriormente."** , esqueci de explicar que era em uma por vez, usando a sintaxe '.on' , ela apaga todos os elementos gerados que possui a mesma classe declarada, não apenas o que foi clicado.
Imagino que seja mais complicado diferenciar cada elemento gerado, mas é possivel?

Comment: @WesleyFerreira então queres que o `close-link` apague só o `close" que estiver dentro desse `ui-widget-content` é isso? Lembra-te de usar classes, mas o que queres pode ser feito assim: `$(this).closest().find('#close').fadeOut();`

Comment: Na verdade não, imagine que eu gere varias caixas, eu preciso fechar especificamente uma, por exemplo a segunda. O problema é que o script fecha tudo que tiver a  classe .close (já transformei ela em classe).

https://jsfiddle.net/wesleyfc000/h6orx7x0/11/

Comment: @WesleyFerreira a resposta que eu dei é o que procuras. No ultimo comentário faltou escrever algo, a ideia é: `$(this).closest('.ui-widget-content').find('#close').fadeOut();`. Dessa maneira a cada click ele vai procurar o pai `'.ui-widget-content.'`  desse elemento clicado, e depois dentro dele, o elemento `close`. Muda para classes e isso vai funcionar.