# Botão retornado via ajax não funciona

Tags: ajax, requisição

Amigos, estou com uma dúvida sobre a recuperação de dados por meio de requisições ajax. Utilizo normalmente o ajax para a busca de dados. O problema surgiu quando resolvi buscar elementos do tipo button e checkbox, pois percebi que os mesmos não funcionam quando são carregados por esse meio.
Vejam abaixo o meu código:

```
$.get(
                "buscar-array-pessoas",
                {plano:var_plano},
                function (retorno){

                $('.caixa-dependentes2').html(retorno);             
});
```

Funciona perfeitamente, encaminho a variavel "plano", e recebo o retorno dentro da classe "caixa-dependentes2". O problema é que há um botão que vem junto com este retorno. Ao clicar no mesmo, percebo que nada acontece. Isso procede?

Para fins de teste, coloquei o meu arquivo "buscar-array-pessoas" para retornar a tag "a":

Arquivo "buscar-array-pessoas":

```
  <a href="#" class="teste">botao teste</div>
  <input name="campo1[]" value=""/>
  <input name="campo2[]" value=""/>
```

Vejam que o retorno é um botão com dois inputs em seguida.

O link é retornado normalmente na página que fez a requisição. Quando clico no mesmo nada acontece.

Veja o jquery:

```
    $(".teste").on('click', function(){  
     alert('Testando botão');
     });
```

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Onde está o código onde adicionas o auscultador de event `.click`? tens de delegar...

Comment: editei a minha pergunta com mais informações =D

Comment: Luis, vê a resposta no link de duplicado, na prática aqui `$('.caixa-dependentes2').on('click', '.teste', function(){  ` deve solucionar o problema.

Comment: Sérgio, você solucionou o meu problema. então devo mencionar a classe de retorno? não sabia disso =D Muito obrigado !

Comment: Luis na resposta que linkei e nesta outra (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5199/129) podes ler sobre isso em respostas minhas e de outros. Se achares algo útil podes votar nas respostas também.

Comment: Farei isso ! Muito obrigado Sergio

Comment: Luis, vamos supor que depois desse link, há um segundo botão. como que eu faço o "resgate" do mesmo com base nisso que você ensinou?  Tentei usar o  "$(this).next();"   mas nao funcionou

Comment: Coloca o HTML em questão para ser mais claro o problema.

Comment: Editei a minha pergunta lá, veja se dá pra entender. Acrescentei dois inputs aós o botão. Usei o  $(this).next() para buscar o proximo input, mas não funcionou.

Comment: Luis, isso já é uma pergunta diferente por isso deixo aqui nos comentários. Podes fazer isso assim: https://jsfiddle.net/0ueut7kp/ Em relação à pergunta aqui a solução está nos links que referi e podes votar lá para premiar boas respostas :)

Comment: Boa tarde Sérgio, obrigado pelo esclarecimento.. Vou postar uma nova pergunta com uma ultima duvida =D