# Busca em Ajax dentro de div clone jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Tenho uma busca em um input que retorna o resultado em ajax, tipo autocomplete que está funcionando (quando digito 3 primeiros digitos ela mostra os resultados), mas quando eu coloco esse input dentro de uma div "clone" (jquery) ela não funciona a busca e não retorna nenhum resultado...

**Coloquei o código no jsfiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/g9dehL8j/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que quando usas `$("#produto").keyup(function(){` o auscultador de evento fica só à escuta de eventos no elemento `#produto` que já existia quando a página foi carregada. Neste caso, e [como o Lucas também referiu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/170638/129), não podes usar ID pois na página só pode haver um elemento com cada ID.

Se usares esse [evento delegado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5199/129), e juntando ambos `#engloba-template` e `#conteudo_engloba` poderia ficar assim:

```
$('#engloba-template, #conteudo_engloba').on('keyup', 'input[name="produto[]"]', function() {
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g9dehL8j/3/

Answer (score 1):

Quando você clona é compreensível repetir o `id`no seu caso. Tente fazer a seleção por uma propriedade qualquer:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="produto" produto name="produto[]">
                                                   ^^^^^^^
```

**JS**

```
$("input[produto]").keyup(function(){ });
```

Comment: obrigado por tentar ajudar, mas não resolveu...

Comment: `+1` por referires o problema de ID duplicado