# jQuery contando automaticamento os ID's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, id

Então moçada, tenho um esquema aqui tipo FAQ que o administrador do site que cadastra as Faqs.
Cada nova pergunta cadastrada gera duas novas divs:

```
<div>Pergunta1</div>
<div>Resposta1</div>
```

Ai eu uso um Jquery pra fazer o efeito de toggle. Quando a pessoa clica na pergunta exibe a resposta:

```
$(function(){ 
    $('#pergunta1').click(function(){
    $('#respota1').toggle(700);         
});
```

Só que na media que as divs de pergunta e resposta são adicionadas eu tenho que adicionar o jQuery manualmente.

Se cadastrar outra:

```
<div>Pergunta2</div>
<div>Resposta2</div>
```

Ai eu teria que fazer outro Jquery mostrado lá em cima alterando...

```
 $(function(){ 
        $('#pergunta2').click(function(){
        $('#respota2').toggle(700);         
 });
```

Teria como o jQuery automatizar isso? Tipo um while ou algo assim?

Comment: Podes explicar o código que _"gera duas novas divs"_? Ele cria IDs nos elementos?

Comment: Qual é o elemento onde essas divs são inseridas? é um mesmo elemento para todas?

Comment: É um while no php que puxa do banco... e um contador que fica no id..

tipo:
<?php
$a = 1;

while(...){ ?>
<div id="pergunta<?php echo $a?>"></div>";
<?php
$a++;
}
?>

Comment: Qual é o elemento onde essas divs são inseridas? é um mesmo elemento para todas?

Comment: Elas ficam dentro de um box com outra div

Comment: Ok, então podes delegar o evento, assim fica simples. Podes [edit] a pergunta com um exemplo de HTML com 2 perguntas, e o que queres que aconteça quando uma é clicada? Assim vai ficar simples de responder ajustado ao teu problema.

Comment: Na verdade eu preciso saber como faço pro jQuery entender que sempre vai haver um novo id=pergunta[x] ?
Sem eu precisar que inserir manual, entendeu ?

Comment: Exato, por isso eu digo que é simples. Mas precisas delegar pois esses elementos não existem ainda quando a página carrega.

Comment: Desculpe amigo @Sergio Sou novo aqui, mas o que seria delegar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tens de delegar esse evento e dizer ao jQuery o que procurar.

Para delegar o evento tens de usar um elemento que já exista, pai dessas divs que vão sendo inseridas.

Para o jQuery saber o que procurar podes usar um [pseudo seletor `^=`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

Assim o código pode ser:

```
$('#elementoPai').on('click', '[id^="pergunta"]', function(){
    var pergunta = this;
    var idResposta = pergunta.id.match(/\d+/)[0];
    var resposta = document.getElementById('resposta_' + idResposta);
    // etc...
});
```

Podes ler mais sobre delegação aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5199/129

Comment: Top irmão vou testar aqui e trago o retorno! Valeu a força!

Comment: @JaiderMasterInfo diz se houver algo que não compreendas. A ideia de delegar é porque não dá para adicionar auscultadores de eventos a elementos que ainda não existem na página quando o JavaScript é lido.