# Diferença entre handlers

Tags: javascript

Usando `JQuery`, percebo duas maneiras principais de se definir handlers para eventos de elementos:

> `$('#elemento').on('click',function() { ... });`

e

> `$(document).delegate('#elemento','click',function() { ... });`

Já passei por situações em que apenas um dos dois funcionava em determinado elemento, porque isso acontece? Qual a diferença entre a funcionalidade deles e entre eles em geral? A qual devo dar preferência?

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual a diferença entre o .on(“click”, function() {}) e o .click(function() {})?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5196/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-o-onclick-function-e-o-clickfunction)

Comment: Ah sim, da forma como eu coloquei o título, o sistema não sugeriu essa outra pergunta semelhante, obrigado