# Diferenças entre $('body').on('click',...) e o $('selector').click()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com uma duvida na declaração de click de um elemento com jQuery, eu sei que possa fazer das seguintes formas:

```
$('body').on('click', '...selector...', function () {...})
```

ou

```
$('...selector...').click(function () {...})
```

Eu sei que da primeira maneira eu não preciso ficar dando *rebind* sempre que surgir um elemento novo na minha página, porém gostaria de saber:

1. Se existe alguma diferença de gasto com memoria, processamento e
   performance entre essa duas variações
2. Se exite mais alguma outra diferença entre elas , além da citada anteriormente.
3. Ou até mesmo, se exite algum motivo que me faça optar a escolher uma das duas alternativas.

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5196/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-o-onclick-function-e-o-clickfunction

Answer (score 0):

A diferença básica entre os dois é em quem você atrela o evento de `click`.

No primeiro caso ele vai capturar o evento quando o mesmo chegar no `body` e tiver origem no seletor desejado. Como os eventos em javascript propagam, quando o usuário clicar no seletor ele vai propagar até o `body` e você vai capturar corretamente.

No segundo você atrela o evento diretamente ao seletor. Quando o clique tiver origem nele, você vai capturar o evento.

E qual a vantagem de atrelar ao `body`? Quando você faz isso, não é necessário que o elemento exista na página. Isso é extremamente útil quando você cria o elemento dinamicamente. Você consegue atrelar o evento a ele sem necessariamente ter criado o elemento ainda.

```
$('body').on('click', '#botao', carregaItems);
var botao = $('<div id="botao">ola</div>');
$('body').append(botao);
```

O `click` no botão vai disparar a função `carregaItems`

No segundo caso, você depende que o elemento esteja presente na página para atrelar o evento a ele. Se o código que atrela o evento for executado antes do código que cria o elemento, o elemento fica sem escuta no evento.

```
$('#botao').click(carregaItems);
var botao = $('<div id="botao">ola</div>');
$('body').append(botao);
```

O `click` no botão **não** vai disparar a função `carregaItems` porque for feito o `bind` do evento em um elemento que não existe no `DOM` ainda.