# Dropdown hover funcionar apenas acima de 1200px

Tags: jquery, dropdown, css-hover

Se alguém puder me ajudar, preciso que o JavaScript do hover funcione apenas na resolução acima de 1200px, fiz o código mas não tá dando certo.

```
$(function() {
    if($(window).width() > 1200) {
        $('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
                $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(100).fadeIn(400);
            },
            function() {
                $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(100).fadeOut(400);
            });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(window).width() > 1200) {
        $('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
                $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(100).fadeIn(400);
            },
            function() {
                $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(100).fadeOut(400);
            });
    }

});
```

Se vc quiser usar enquanto vc redimensiona o window, então va iter que usar o jquery resize

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer a verificação dentro da função do hover, e se for verdadeiro não faz nada, veja o código:

```js
var $meuLink = $('#meuLink');
var $divMostrarOcultar = $('#divMostrarOcultar');

$meuLink
  .on('mouseover', function() {
    var tamanhoJanela = $(window).width();
    if (tamanhoJanela > 1200)
      return;

    console.log('A janela tem ' + tamanhoJanela + 'px');
  })
  .on('mouseout', function() {
    var tamanhoJanela = $(window).width();
    if (tamanhoJanela > 1200)
      return;

    console.log('A janela tem ' + tamanhoJanela + 'px');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="meuLink">Passe o mouse</a>
<div id="divMostrarOcultar">Conteudo a mostrar/ocultar</div>
```

Nesse caso, se a janela for maior que 1200 não irá fazer nada, mas caso seja menor ou igual irá imprimir no console do navegador o tamanho da janela.

Apenas uma observação ao seu código, prefira utilizar `.on('event'` ao invéz de utilizar o evento diretamente. Veja [nessa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5199/34771) resposta o motivo.

**Agora como poderia ficar em seu código:**

```
$('ul.nav li.dropdown')
  .on('mouseover', function() {
    if (janelaMaiorQue(1200))
      return;

    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(100).fadeIn(400);
  })
  .on('mouseout', function() {
    if (janelaMaiorQue(1200))
      return;

    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(100).fadeOut(400);
  });

function janelaMaiorQue(tamanho) {
  var tamanhoJanela = $(window).width();

  return tamanhoJanela > tamanho;
}
```