# Como faço para executar os script após carregar a pagina

Tags: javascript, framework7

estou com uma dúvida sobre o framework7, como faço para executar os scripts depois de carregado dinamicamente a página, exemplo:

```
mainView.router.loadPage("pagina.html)


[script que registram eventos nos botoes da pagina acima]

$("#capturarFoto").unbind().bind("click",function () {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccessCapturaImagem, onFailCapturaImagem, 
 {
        quality: 50,
        correctOrientation: true,
        encodingType: navigator.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
    });
});

$("#procurarFoto").unbind().bind("click",function () {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccessCapturaImagem, onFailCapturaImagem,
        {
            destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
            encodingType: navigator.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            correctOrientation: true
        }
    );
});
```

Quando eu faço isso ele não registra os eventos no botão, alguem sabe o por que?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar o evento *pageInit*, [link](https://framework7.io/docs/get-started.html#scripts-for-specific-page)

```
$(document).on('pageInit', function (e) {
    //as funções de bind
    $("#capturarFoto").unbind().bind()...
});
```

Answer (score 3):

O proprio Framework7 tem uma forma de executar funcoes toda vez que acessar uma pagina.

```
app.onPageInit('pagina', function (page) {
  // Sua função...
})
```

o `app` é a atribuição do `framework7`, em geral, são definidos como `app` ou `MyApp`.
O nome da `pagina` passado no `onPageInit` é definido logo no seu arquivo. Ex:

```
<div class="page" data-page="pagina">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Como você esta usando jQuery/Zepto você pode usar a [**delegação de eventos**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5196/3635) e ao invés de executar a todo momento bastaria fazer assim:

```
$(document).on("click", "#capturarFoto", function () {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccessCapturaImagem, onFailCapturaImagem, {
        quality: 50,
        correctOrientation: true,
        encodingType: navigator.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
    });
});

$(document).on("click", "#procurarFoto", function () {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccessCapturaImagem, onFailCapturaImagem, {
        destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        encodingType: navigator.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        correctOrientation: true
    });
});
```

Este script deve ser executado apenas uma vez.