# Função .click não funciona em botões que foram gerados dinamicamente pela função .html?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
var nReqAJAX = nReqAR
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../controller/ajax.selectItemRequisicaoPesquisar.php",
    data: {'numeroRequisicao': nReqAJAX},
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(res) {
        if(res == null)
        {
            $('#modalReqInvalida').modal('show');
        }
        else
        {
            var html = res.reduce(function(string, obj, i) {
                return string + '<tr class="text-center"><td style="vertical-align: middle;">' + i + '</td><td style="vertical-align: middle;">' + obj.nome_GAThemocomponente + '</td><td style="vertical-align: middle;">' + obj.qtd_GATitemRequisicao + '</td><td style="vertical-align: middle;">' + obj.frequencia_GATitemRequisicao + '</td><td style="vertical-align: middle;">' + obj.cirurgia_GATitemRequisicao + '</td><td><button id="1" name="btnAtender" class="btn btn-success" style="width: 100%;">Atender Item</button></td></tr>'
            }, '');
            $("#tab_logic tbody").html(html);
        }
    }
});

$("button[name='btnAtender']").on(function(){
    alert('teste');
});
```

É executado um `AJAX` ao carregar a pagina, caso o retorno seja nulo, mostro um modal, caso o resultado não seja nulo, "desenho" uma tabela usando a função `.html`, até ai tudo bem, o problema é que ao desenhar a tabela, eu desenho também um `button` na ultima celula e digo que o nome desse `button` é `btnAtender`, porém, eu gostaria de fazer a seguinte função:

```
$("button[name='btnAtender']").click(function(){
    alert('teste');
});
```

Ou seja, quando o usuario clicar no `button` `btnAtender`, vai aparecer um `alert` mostrando um texto, porém essa função simples não está funcionando, aparentemente por estar sendo executada quando a partir do click de um botão gerado dinamicamente, para efeito de teste, criei um `<button name="btn">btn teste</button>` no html da pagina e a função funcionou.

O que eu poderia fazer funcionar a função do `alert`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não faça desta forma:

```
$("button[name='btnAtender']").click(function(){
    alert('teste');
});
```

E sim desta forma:

```
$("button[name='btnAtender']").on('click', function(){
    alert('teste');
});
```

> "É basicamente como é feita a associação para o elemento. .click se
>   aplica ao DOM corrente, enquanto o .on (usando delegação) continuará
>   valendo para novos elementos adicionados ao DOM depois da associação
>   do evento."

Fonte: [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5196/qual-a-diferença-entre-o-onclick-function-e-o-clickfunction](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5196/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-o-onclick-function-e-o-clickfunction)

Comment: Tinha escolhido uma outra reposta como "correta", porém essa também funcionou e teve um menção importante para ganhar conhecimento, já que o link disponibilizado me ensinou coisas que eu ainda não tinha conhecimento. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Não, pois o `DOM` já foi renderizado, mas você pode resolver fazendo referencia ao `document`

```js
$(document).on('click', '#gerar', function(){
   $('body').append('<button id="gerado">Executar Alert</button>')
})

$(document).on('click', '#gerado', function(){
    alert('oi')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="gerar">Gerar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vou explicar o que acontece. Quando você coloca este primeiro código, o botão btnAtender ainda não existe. Há várias formas de solucionar isso, mas o que resolveria de forma rápida (e feia) seria colocar o código:

```
$("button[name='btnAtender']").on('click',function(){
    alert('teste');
});
```

logo abaixo deste:

`$("#tab_logic tbody").html(html);`

Dessa forma o botão já vai estar na página quando o `click` for associado.

Tente assim:

```
var nReqAJAX = nReqAR
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../controller/ajax.selectItemRequisicaoPesquisar.php",
    data: {'numeroRequisicao': nReqAJAX},
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(res) {
        if(res == null)
        {
            $('#modalReqInvalida').modal('show');
        }
        else
        {
            var html = res.reduce(function(string, obj, i) {
                return string + '<tr class="text-center"><td style="vertical-align: middle;">' + i + '</td><td style="vertical-align: middle;">' + obj.nome_GAThemocomponente + '</td><td style="vertical-align: middle;">' + obj.qtd_GATitemRequisicao + '</td><td style="vertical-align: middle;">' + obj.frequencia_GATitemRequisicao + '</td><td style="vertical-align: middle;">' + obj.cirurgia_GATitemRequisicao + '</td><td><button id="1" name="btnAtender" class="btn btn-success" style="width: 100%;">Atender Item</button></td></tr>'
            }, '');
            $("#tab_logic tbody").html(html);
            $("button[name='btnAtender']").on(function(){
               alert('teste');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Não é dessa forma que o _event listener_ trabalha. Veja um exemplo rápido no [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/gabrielheming/pen/vebVaG) e veja que sempre será adicionado um novo _event listener_ no botão já existente, e nunca no botão adicionado.

Comment: Apesar de parecer estranha a resposta, consegui solucionar o problema, a unica diferença que teve é que usei a função `.click` ao invés de `.on` como você mencionou, feito isso, funcionou igual eu desejava. Talvez essa não seja a forma correta de fazer o que eu gostaria, mas como é apenas um trabalho da faculdade, atende as minhas necessidades. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Defina uma `promisse`, fica assim...

**Defina o evento de click como uma função**

```
function comp(){
    $("button[name='btnAtender']").on('click',function(){
        alert('teste');
    });
}
```

**Ao colocar o html**

```
$("#tab_logic tbody").html(html).promise().done(function(){
    comp();
});
```

Sua função vai se estender, logo não vai ser necessário chamar o código todo novamente.