# Qual a diferença entre .on(), .click(), .blur(), bind()?

Tags: jquery

E se existe mais algum, qual seria? E a diferença desse "mais algum" para os demais acima.

Obs: Sei que tem, não estou afirmando que não tem,  se alguém de uma forma didática souber responder com alguns exemplos com código seria bastante legal.

Comment: A tua pergunta é a mesma que esta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5199/129 ?

Comment: Não é não, Sergio. Tem algumas coisas a mais que eu queria saber na minha, mas obrigado!

Comment: Podes explicar as diferenças desta pergunta em relação à outra para ficar mais claro?

Comment: No caso queria saber a diferença entre todos esses eventos, não somente entre o click e o on. Pôs chegou numa parte do curso aqui que o rapaz começou a usar esses eventos, mas disse pra procurarmos na internet porque ele não ia se aprofundar muito, sendo que o curso é de PHP. No caso gostaria de saber mesmo.

Comment: Queres saber a explicação de cada um desses eventos?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Existem muitos *triggers* para o jQuery, segue uma breve explicação:

1 - O método `.click()` é o próprio nome, ele vai disparar uma ação quando houver um '*click*' em algum elemento informado no seletor:

```js
$('.button').click(function(){
alert('O botão foi clicado');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='button'>Botao</button>
```

2 - O método `.blur()` vem do 'escorregar', ou seja, ele dispara uma ação quando o ponteiro sai do elemento selecionado:

Obs: para disparar digite algo no *input* e pressione a tecla <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

```js
$('.input').blur(function(){
alert('O foco saiu do input');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='input' type='text'>
```

3 - Ja o `.bind()` e o `.on()` não são o evento por si só, eles são *event handlers*, ou em português, manipuladores de eventos, sua função é verificar se um evento foi disparado. A diferença entre os dois é que o método [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) se tornou obsoleto nas versão 3.0 do jQuery, ficando recomendado o uso do método `.on()`, que também permite acessar elementos que não estavam no [DOM](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo_de_Objeto_de_Documentos) original, ainda existem os métodos *handlers* `.live()`, que também está obsoleto então não irei explicar, e o método `.delegate()`, que embora também esteja obsoleto (para a versão 3.0), acho legal explicar, pois ele permite navegar partindo de um elemento escolhido, não somente do documento, ganhando desempenho em uma ação.

Segue exemplo do método `.on()`:

```js
$(document).on('click','.add-botao',function(){
$('.botoes').append('<button class="alertar">Borão gerado via js</button>');
})

$(document).on('click','.alertar',function(){
   alert('botão gerado via js clicado');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='add-botao'>Add Botão</button>
<div class='botoes'></div>
```

Exemplo de `.delegate()`:

```js
$( "table" ).delegate( "td", "click", function() {
  alert($(this).html())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
  <td>
  1
  </td>
  <td>
  2
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
  3
  </td>
  <td>
  4
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Existem uma série de eventos jQuery que fazer ações expecíficas, segue lista dos que eu mais utilizo:

- [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) => Dispara quando o valor do elemento muda.
- [`.contextmenu()`](http://api.jquery.com/contextmenu/) => Dispara ao clicar com o botão direito do mouse.
- [`.mouseover()`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) => Dispara quando o mouse passa sobre o elemento selecionado.
- [`.ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) => Dispara quando o elemento selecionado está pronto.

Segue documentação oficial dos *events*, pois são muitos pra descrever em uma única resposta:

- [Eventos jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/)

OBS: O método `.on` permite navegar partindo de um elemento especifico, assim como o *delegate*, por esse motivo o método `.bind()` e `.delegate()` foram descontinuados.