# Quando clico no texto ele não muda (js)

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Estou aprendendo JS e não consigo entender o porque de não mudar o texto do h1 quando clico no mesmo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Testes JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1 id="title">Somente alguns testes em JS</h1>

 <script>
  var x = document.getElementById("title");
  x.onclick = {
   clicado: 0,
   click: function(){
    this.innerHTML = "teste";
    clicado = 1;
   },
   check: function(){
    if(clicado === 0){
     return false;
    }else if (clicado === 1){
     return true;
    }
   }
  };
  x.onclick.click();
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: De onde você tirou esse código ?

Comment: Eu que escrevi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A propriedade [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) retorna o código do manipulador de eventos de clique no elemento atual.

A utilização correta seria:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("title");
x.onclick = function() {
    this.innerHTML = 'O usuário clicou, o titulo foi alterado!';
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Somente alguns testes em JS</h1>
```

Note que não tem a necessidade de **checar** se foi clicado. Também pode ser feito assim:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("title");
function minha_funcao() {
    this.innerHTML = 'O usuário clicou, o titulo foi alterado!';
}
x.onclick = minha_funcao;
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Somente alguns testes em JS</h1>
```

Utilizando objeto:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("title");
var objeto= {
    clicks: 0,
    check: function() {
      if (this.clicks === 0) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    },
    click: function() {
      x.innerHTML = 'O usuário clicou, o titulo foi alterado!';
      objeto.clicks++;
      console.log(objeto.clicks);
    }
};
x.onclick = objeto.click;
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Somente alguns testes em JS</h1>
```

Você também pode utilizar o método [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener) para adicionar um evento ao elemento.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("title");
var objeto = {
  clicks: 0,
  check: function() {
    console.log(objeto.clicks);
    if (objeto.clicks === 1) {
      x.addEventListener('click', objeto.click_B);
    }
  },
  click_A: function() {
    objeto.clicks++;
    x.innerHTML = 'O usuário clicou, o titulo foi alterado! Clicou ' + objeto.clicks + ' vez';
    objeto.check();
  },
  click_B: function() {
    x.innerHTML = 'O usuário clicou, o titulo foi alterado novamente! Clicou ' + objeto.clicks + ' vezes';
  },
};
x.addEventListener('click', objeto.click_A);
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Somente alguns testes em JS</h1>
```

#### Observação:

A maneira como o **AP** descreveu em sua pergunta, funciona desde que faça:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("title");
x.onclick = {
  click: function() {
    console.log('Ele clicou no H1');
  }
}.click;
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Somente alguns testes em JS</h1>
```

Mas um ponto extremamente importante a se notar, é que caso ele tenha outro método nesse objeto, o mesmo não pode ser executado. Veja o exemplo a seguir:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("title");
x.onclick = {
  funcao_a: function() {
    console.log('Função A');
  },
  click: function() {
    console.log('Click');
    x.onclick.funcao_a();
  }
}.click;
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Somente alguns testes em JS</h1>
```

#### Referências

- [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)
- [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener)

Comment: Você poderia me explicar melhor oque seria o código do manipulador de eventos ?

Comment: Um tutorial em Português: [Manipulando Eventos](http://braziljs.github.io/eloquente-javascript/chapters/manipulando-eventos/)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode também usar jQuery para criar um *event handler* (manipulador de eventos) para o elemento. No caso, para o evento `click`:

```
$("#title").click(function(){
    $(this).html("teste");
});
```

ou

```
$("#title").on("click", function(){
    $(this).html("teste");
});
```

A diferença entre um e outro você pode conferir **[nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5201/8063)**.

```js
$("#title").click(function(){
    $(this).html("teste");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="title">Somente alguns testes em JS</h1>
```

> Caso não conheça jQuery, é uma biblioteca JavaScript que facilita a
>   manipulação dos elementos DOM. Você pode carregar a biblioteca
>   adicionando o script no seu `<head>`:
>
> ```
> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
> ```

Caso queira chamar um [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) (mesma coisa que você fez com `x.onclick.click();`):

```js
$("#title").click(function(){
    $(this).html("teste");
});

$("#title").trigger("click");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="title">Somente alguns testes em JS</h1>
```

Answer (score -1):

Tente

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Testes JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="title" onclick = "teste();">Somente alguns testes em JS</h1>
<script> function teste(){ var x = document.getElementById("title"); x.innerHTML = "teste";}</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fiz do x.onclick um objeto para treinar o JS, por isso gostaria de entender o porque de não funcionar desta forma entendeu ?

Comment: Favor, **tente** é resposta duvidosa, explique ao **AP** aonde ele está errando, não responda apenas por responder.