# Executar método que esta dentro do evento "onclick"

Tags: javascript

Ao responder essa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/270324), me deparei com a seguinte situação. Note que `onclick` em `x` é um objeto com dois métodos, quando o elemento recebe o clique executa o método `click` que por sua vez era pra executar o método `funcao_a`, mas retorna o seguinte erro:

> TypeError: x.onclick.funcao_a is not a function at HTMLHeadingElement.click

```js
var x = document.getElementById("title");
x.onclick = {
  funcao_a: function() {
    console.log('Função A');
  },
  click: function() {
    console.log('Click');
    x.onclick.funcao_a();
  }
};

x.onclick = x.onclick.click;
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Somente alguns testes em JS</h1>
```

Mas não acontece o mesmo quando tenho um objeto com um nome diferente, como por exemplo: `x.objeto`.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("title");
x.objeto = {
  funcao_a: function() {
    console.log('Função A');
  },
  click: function() {
    console.log('Click');
    x.objeto.funcao_a();
  }
};

x.onclick = x.objeto.click;
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Somente alguns testes em JS</h1>
```

*Minha pergunta é: É possível acessar esse método como no primeiro exemplo? Se sim como ?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade o problema está no que assumiu que ficou em `x.onclick`

> Note que `onclick` em `x` é um objeto ...

O `onclick` em `x` ficou na verdade com uma função, algo que consegue comprovar com o operador `typeof`

```js
var x = document.getElementById("title");
x.onclick = {
  funcao_a: function() {
    console.log('Função A');
  },
  click: function() {
    console.log('Click');
    x.onclick.funcao_a();
  }
}.click;

console.log(typeof x.onclick);
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Somente alguns testes em JS</h1>
```

Porque quando construiu o objeto apenas ficou com a função `click` ao fazer `.click` no final.

Comecemos por considerar outro exemplo simples:

```js
let usuario = {
    nome: "Carlos",
    idade: 25
};

let nome = usuario.nome;
console.log(nome);
```

Aqui torna-se claro que a variável `nome` vai ter o valor `"Carlos"`.

Mas podemos construir um exemplo semelhante ao seu sem guardar o objeto numa variável:

```js
let nome = {
    nome: "Carlos",
    idade: 25
}.nome;

console.log(nome);
```

A diferença é que neste caso construímos o objeto todo mas apenas ficamos com o nome, o que faz com que o resto da informação não seja acessível. Na verdade o objeto foi instanciado e utilizado apenas naquela linha, não ficando com nenhuma referência para ele, e por isso não sendo acessível no resto do código.

É exatamente este o problema que o seu primeiro exemplo tem.

Se quisesse tornar ainda mais claro poderia formatar ligeiramente o exemplo e acrescentar parêntesis reforçar visualmente que sobre o objeto criado irá ficar apenas com o nome:

```js
let nome = ({nome:"Carlos",idade: 25}).nome;
console.log(nome);
```

Comment: Até aqui entendi, mas mesmo assim o erro persiste. Veja que alterei na pergunta, chamando `x.onclick = x.onclick.click;` quando executa a função `click` a função `funcao_a` chamada nela não funciona. Retorna o erro.

Comment: Agora o problema é ligeiramente diferente. Pois primeiro guarda o objeto com `x.onclick = { .... };`. Mas depois tira o objeto de lá e mete apenas a função com `x.onclick = x.onclick.click;`, deixando o objeto anterior novamente inacessível. No final do dia se `onclick` é função não vai poder fazer `onclick.qualquercoisa()`. Se ainda assim não tiver ficado claro é só avisar que eu extendo a minha resposta para contemplar esse outro cenário também.

Comment: Neste caso somente o segundo exemplo funcionaria corretamente. Obrigado pelo esclarecimento, isso nem passou pela minha mente.

Comment: @wmsouza Exatamente só o segundo exemplo é que funciona corretamente. Fico contente de ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

No primeiro código, o `click` sublinhado na imagem abaixo não representa nada além de uma instância do objeto `x.onclick`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu poderia usar qualquer nome, por exemplo `abc`:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("title");
x.onclick = {
  funcao_a: function() {
    console.log('Função A');
  },
  abc: function() {
    console.log('Click');
    x.onclick.funcao_a();
  }
}.abc;
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Somente alguns testes em JS</h1>
```

No primeiro exemplo você não consegue acessar `funcao_a()` porque o objeto `x.onclick` está apontado apenas para `click` (no meu exemplo, `abc`) em:

```
}.click;
```

No seu segundo exemplo, você não atribuiu o objeto a nenhuma instância, logo você consegue acessar qualquer instância dentro dele chamando pelo nome:

```
x.onclick = x.onclick.click;
```

ou

```
x.onclick = x.onclick.funcao_a;
```

Veja o que o console mostra dentro de `x.onclick` do primeiro exemplo, apenas a função dentro de `click:`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já no segundo exemplo, o console mostra todas as instâncias disponíveis no objeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Logo, não tem como você acessar a instância `funcao_a:` no primeiro exemplo porque ela não está visível para o `onclick` em questão.