# On("Click") JavaScript não funciona

Tags: php, javascript

Fiz um script para pegar o valor de um elemento que é gerado no php, sempre que esse elemento é clicado mas ele não está funcionado

```
<script>
    $('.collection-item').on('click',function(){    
        var  idA = $(".collection-item").val();  
        alert("tete");  
        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'Chamadas/listarMunicipios.php', 
            type: 'POST', 
            data: { id: idA},
            success: function(data) { 

                window.location.reload(); 
            } 
        }); 

    });
</script>
```

Elemento

```
echo '<a href="#!" value="" class="collection-item">TESTE</a>';
```

Comment: Esse elemento é adicionado dinamicamente ?

Comment: ele é adicionado em um foreach, no caso são vários elementos iguais com somente texto diferente, eles também tem a mesma classe, a intenção é que quando  qualquer um desses elementos forem clicados eu conseguir pegar o value deles

Comment: Tente: `$(document).on('click', '.collection-item', ...`

Comment: Funcionou obrigado :D, posta como resposta pra eu marcar como correto

Comment: Já existe uma pergunta falando do assunto, então votar lá na resposta!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Só pra caso alguém venha para esta página..

o código está correto como exemplificado por min abaixo:

```js
$('.collection-item').on('click',function(){    
        var  idA = $(".collection-item").val();  
        alert("funcionou");  
        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cdYItaXpvm?indent=2', 
            type: 'GET', 
            success: function(data) { 

                console.log(data);
            } 
        }); 

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#!" value="" class="collection-item">TESTE</a>
```

O problema é que esta gerando um código usando o php, e o script precisa referenciar o documento, por isso necessário o uso de :

```
$(document).on('click', '.collection-item'
```

no código jquery.

Você consegue tambem caso gere pelo php esse código dentro de uma funcão

```
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {
   //codigo do clik aqui dentro
});
```

ou usando a versão curta:

```
// Shorthand for $( document ).ready()
$(function() {
    //codigo do clik aqui dentro
});
```

link de uma pergunta e resposta ja criados anteriormente

[Qual a diferença entre o .on("click", function() {}) e o .click(function() {})?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5196/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-o-onclick-function-e-o-clickfunction)

**Outra coisa interessante**

Não é recomendado o usar o php para gerar a view, existem novos padrões de arquitetura que nós aconselha criar algo mais modular, separando o front do backend, deixando todos independentes. um padrão bem usado é o restAPI[inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://becode.com.br/o-que-e-api-rest-e-restful/)