# Mostrar DIV quando clico no Botão via JQuery

Tags: html, jquery

Tô usando o seguinte código pra mostrar a DIV quando clico no botão:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
  $(".div").css("display","flex");
});
```

Está funcionando normalmente quando clico no botão criado direto no html.
Acontece que eu quando eu crio o mesmo botão com jquery ele não funciona.

```
var divs = '<div class="col-2"><button data-action="addCart" class="addCart" type="button" name="button">+</button></div>';

        $(".container").append(divs);
```

Tanto o botão que eu estava criando direto no html quanto o que é gerado via jquery (pq são vários divs) estão exatamente iguais na inspeção do chrome, mas o segundo não muda o CSS para flex. Tô usando a mesma classe para ambos.

Comment: Nao sei ao certo, mas talvez não funcione pq ele foi criado depois que o DOM foi renderizado... não sei se resolve, mas vc pode por o script no final do documento depois de todo o conteúdo e testar pra ver se resolve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realmente ele não vai funcionar porque o elemento foi criado depois que o DOM foi renderizado.
Mas você pode contornar isso da seguinte maneira:

```
$(document).on('click', '.button', function(){
    $(".div").css("display","flex");
});
```

O método `on` trabalha para elementos adicionados dinamicamente.

> Complementando:
>
> [Difference between .on('click') vs .click()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11878976/6788964)
>
> [Qual a diferença entre o .on(“click”, function() {}) e o .click(function() {})?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5201/67686)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado!!