# Após o recarregamento, o listener do jQuery não funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quando eu clico em um botão `.click`, meu JS roda uma função e atualiza os campos com a classe `.click`. Mas por que quando o HTML é atualizado e se clica em `.click` de novo não acontece nada como se a classe não existisse?

JavaScript:

```js
$(function () {
    $(".click").click(function () {
        $.get("http://localhost/test/api.php", function (data) {
            alert(data);
            $(".content").html(data);
        })
    })
})
```

HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="content">
    <div class="click">ops</div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="functions.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Quando eu clico pela primeira vez em `.click`, busca-se o HTML de `api.php` (`<div class="click">eita</div>`), que é colocado em `.content`.

Porém se eu clicar de novo em `.click`  depois de recarregar, o conteúdo com o HTML do AJAX simplesmente não faz mais nada. Por quê?

Comment: Qual é o HTML da página `http://localhost/test/api.php`? Edite a pergunta para o incluir.

Comment: `code` <div class="click">eita</div>

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que você está anexando o *listener* de evento na `<div class="click">ops</div>`, que irá ser removida da página quando você utilizar o método `html`. Desse modo, o seu *listener* de evento também será perdido.

Você deve fazer uso do mecanismo de [delegação de evento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5196/69296) para resolver isso. Anexe o *listener* em `.content`, que não é removido da página:

Veja um exemplo (sem AJAX, mas ilustra bem):

```js
$('.content').on('click', '.click', function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
  
  $('.content').html('<div class="click">Segundo</div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
  <div class="click">Primeiro</div>
</div>
```

Note, que o *listener* foi anexado em `.content`, mas será delegado aos elementos de seletor `.click` (segundo argumento do método [`on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/)).

Comment: SHOW ! O PROBLEMA ERA BEM ESSE MESMO MEU AMIGO, VLLW

Comment: @GilbertoGonçalves, Se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar.

Comment: @GilbertoGonçalves veja [como agradecer](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/605/como-dizer-obrigado-em-respostas/787#787).